# How to determine magnitude of trigonometric function? C++

Tags: c++, function

```
>     if (((test>=0) && (test<=90)) || ((test>270) && (test<=360))){n_y=1;}
>     else {n_y=-1;}
```

I need the magnitude of trigonometric function in order to determine the sign of the trigonometric function for an angle falling into a particular quadrant.

My plan is to replace the code above with something equivalent.

Here is what I want to do in pseudo-code.

```
n_y = cos(test) / (magnitude of cos (test));
```

This will give me same thing. Abs() only takes integers. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `abs` or the `fabs` family is all you need to find FP magnitude. But it sounds like what you actually want is quadrant from degrees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what `Abs()` you're using, [fabs from the C++ standard takes doubles just fine](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/fabs/).

But you don't really want magnitude, because then you're stuck doing an expensive division.

Instead just use a [signum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903954/is-there-a-standard-sign-function-signum-sgn-in-c-c) function.

Comment: Brilliant! no signum in C++, but the link led me to copysign

Which does the above in one line:
n_y=copysignf(1, cos(angle));

Comment: @seaworthy: `copysign` is nonstandard.

Comment: @potatoswatter: it's part of math.h, isn't that a standard?

Comment: @seaworthy: It's standard C99 but not standard C++.

Comment: If not being standard C++ bothers you, the answers to the question I linked to supply several other ways of implementing signum.  Of course, the original code is much faster than the new code calling `cos`, but didn't handle non-canonical angles.  I'd think that modulo would still be faster though.

Comment: i guess it's a bit hacky, BUT the sign of float/double should be contained in the most significant bit of the number, just as for signed integers. (For IEEE-754 standard floating point)

Answer (score 0):

Did you `#include <cmath>` to get the floating-point overloads for `abs`?

As for finding the quadrant, if `0 <= test <= 360`, and you want to test `90 < test <= 270` just use `90 < test && test <= 270`. There is a continuous range between the two discontinuous ranges you are currently testing. However, your particular example defines things asymmetrically as it maps 0 => 1 and 270 => -1.