# Zero-crossing Sign function

Tags: c++, function, math, sign

I have written a Sign function and am wondering whether it is correct or not (Stupid question to ask, I know!) I'm just interested in knowing whether this is the best method to solve this particular task:

```
template<typename T>
T sign(T n)
{
  if(n < 0) return -1;
  if(n > 0) return 1;
  return 0;
}
```

Would this give accurate enough results for large datasets? Can anyone see a problem, that I haven't come across that may arise when putting this into a real-life context?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a standard sign function (signum, sgn) in C/C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903954/is-there-a-standard-sign-function-signum-sgn-in-c-c)

Comment: Wouldn't it be better with a return type of `int`? Currently you are depending that `-1` and `1` are convertable to type `T`.

Comment: What do you mean by “accurate enough results”? It gives *exact* results (unless you are using a truly weird type which cannot exactly – but approximately – represent 0, 1 and -1). How more accurate do you want them?

Comment: @john Hey, thank you! So instead of using templates to decide the return type, just return an int?

Comment: @KonradRudolph Well, it doesn't since it's a template, but implemented just for `int` and `double` variants.

Comment: Looks fine to me.  I prefer your version to the proposed duplicate - easy to understand and shouldn't be significantly slower.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be See my edited comment.

Comment: @KonradRudolph You mean like complex numbers?

Comment: Why has this been closed / I received bad rep? It's a question->this is a forum for programming questions ... It's clear, and is not really a duplicate of the previous post

Comment: @Let_Me_Be No. I mean there is *no* (realistic) type which is unable to represent the result accurately (note that `unsigned` doesn’t qualify even though it cannot represent -1 at all, precisely because it cannot represent it *at all* – and furthermore the result would still be correct).

Comment: @Phorce Code review is explicitly offtopic. There is a specialized stackexchange site for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would change `return 0;` to `return n;`. If `n` is `NaN`, `sign` should return `NaN`, not `0`.