# is there a function in c/c++ that gets integer sign and removes value?

Tags: c++, c, integer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a standard sign function (signum, sgn) in C/C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903954/is-there-a-standard-sign-function-signum-sgn-in-c-c)

I mean something like an analog to `abs()` which removes sign but in this case a function that takes any negative integer and returns `-1`, `1` for positive and `0` remains unchanged ?

(Yes, I know I could easily write that on my own, but I ask here if such a function is provided in a language.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  It doesn't exist in the standard lib.