# An algorithm to wrap/overflow number based on max value

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

Anyone for a challenge? I am looking for an efficient algorithm to achieve a wrap/overflow behavior for a number fixed with max value.

Say, the max possible number value is defined as:

```
#define MAX_NUMBER_VALUE 100
```

And a function `translate` that takes a signed 32-bit or 64-bit integer value and "wraps it around" using that MAX_NUMBER_VALUE constant:

```
int_fast8_t translate(int_fast32_t value) {

  if (abs(value) > MAX_NUMBER_VALUE) {
    return ...; // This!
  }

  return value;
}
```

The expected input and output:

```
translate(55)   => 55
translate(100)  => 100
translate(101)  => -100
translate(102)  => -99
translate(200)  => -1
translate(202)  => 1
translate(300)  => 99
translate(-40)  => -40
translate(-100) => -100
translate(-101) => 100
translate(-102) => 99
translate(-200) => 1
translate(-201) => 0
...
```

The value "walks" around the number as if it was a round planet. This does look similar to how C/C++ handles int overflow conditions. I wonder if there is a fast and efficient way to achieve this kind of wrapping? Like with bit shifting or other bitwise operations?

Comment: Are you just describing the `%` operator?

Comment: You basically need to do a modulus over `MAX_NUMBER_VALUE*2 - 1`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int_fast8_t translate(int_fast32_t value) {
  return sgn(value)*( (abs(value)+MAX)%(2*MAX+1)-MAX )
}
```

should do it, assuming modular division is defined for the `int_fast32_t` type

edited to include handling of negative numbers but it looks a bit messier now. For a smart implementation of sgn(x) see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903954/is-there-a-standard-sign-function-signum-sgn-in-c-c)

Comment: Are you sure you want the range of the output to be the _closed_ interval [-MAX_NUMBER_VALUE, MAX_NUMBER_VALUE]? It would be more natural to use the semi-open interval [-MAX_NUMBER_VALUE, MAX_NUMBER_VALUE) or (-MAX_NUMBER_VALUE, MAX_NUMBER_VALUE]

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think this will wrap for negative numbers, say -101: `(-101+100)%(2*100+1)-100 = -101`.

Comment: Of course, sorry. I should have paid attention to the previous comment about "careful handling of negative numbers"

Comment: Either my math is wrong or it is still not wrapping for negative numbers: `-101 => -1*(101+100)%(2*100+1)-100 = -100`! :)

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you're just describing the `%` operator, with some careful treatment of negative numbers.

Comment: You should elaborate on this "careful treatment of negative numbers" - this is the important aspect of the question I believe. I doubt the answer will be very useful as is.

Comment: Yes, I am well aware the modulus operator is most likely unavoidable here. Still, I wonder if there are any alternatives as with bit shifting.

Comment: @Sim: For arbitrary values of `MAX`, not really.  You could always define a massive lookup table, but that probably wouldn't be faster due to terrible cache performance!

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Thanks. I am just curious how would I write the wrapping with bit shifting if my MAX_NUMBER_VALUE could be expressed as 2^n?

Comment: @Sim: Assuming 2's complement, then you should be able to just do `x &= (2*n-1); if (x >= n) x -= 2*n;`.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your `input + MAX_VALUE` is less than the max value of the integral type in question I think you can use this, not even requiring the initial `abs` check:

```
return ((input + MAX_VALUE) % (MAX_VALUE * 2 + 1)) - MAX_VALUE;
```

Comment: nrussell has suggested this before, however this does not wrap for negative numbers, say -101: `(-101+100)%(100*2+1)-100 = -101`