# Fast sign of integer in C

Tags: c, micro-optimization, signed-integer

There is a sign function in C:

```
int sign(int x)
{
    if(x > 0) return 1;
    if(x < 0) return -1;
    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately, comparison cost is very high, so I need to modify function in order reduce the number of comparisons.

I tried the following:

```
int sign(int x)
{
    int result;
    result = (-1)*(((unsigned int)x)>>31);

    if (x > 0) return 1;

    return result;
}
```

In this case I get only one comparison.

Is there any way to avoid comparisons at all?

**EDIT** [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903954/is-there-a-standard-sign-function-signum-sgn-in-c-c) does not give an answer for a question as all answers are C++, uses comparison (that I supposed to avoid) or does not return `-1`, `+1`, `0`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903954/is-there-a-standard-sign-function-signum-sgn-in-c-c

Comment: Or more specifically, this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1904074/253056

Comment: I think after compilation the original variant will a lot faster with only one test and two condintional jump

Comment: A good compiler should optimise the original version to a branchless instruction stream anyway.

Comment: sign = +1 | (v >> (sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT - 1));  // if v < 0 then -1, else +1   --From the link given by @PaulR

Comment: What do you need, a fast calculation or something interesting but not so fast? I see no point avoiding only one (pseudo)comparition with 0 in favor to some other swith and sing change

Comment: @Paul R : +1... but only a very bad compliler will not optimize this

Comment: @Alex: Your claim about the duplicate is false. It contains (at least)  two C-compatible answers without branches.

Comment: @GManNickG can you please tell which one?

Comment: "Comparison cost is very high" : how so? Comparing with zero is usually cheap or free, as on every architecture I know the SIGN and ZERO status register bits are set automatically.

Comment: @Alex: The second comment on your question.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

First of all, integer comparison is very cheap. It's *branching* that can be expensive (due to the risk of branch mispredictions).

I have benchmarked your function on a Sandy Bridge box using gcc 4.7.2, and it takes about 1.2ns per call.

The following is about 25% faster, at about 0.9ns per call:

```
int sign(int x) {
    return (x > 0) - (x < 0);
}
```

The machine code for the above is completely branchless:

```
_sign:
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    testl   %edi, %edi
    setg    %al
    shrl    $31, %edi
    subl    %edi, %eax
    ret
```

Two things are worth pointing out:

1. The base level of performance is very high.
2. Eliminating branching does improve performance here, but not dramatically.

Answer (score 6):

```
int sign(int x)
{
    // assumes 32-bit int and 2s complement signed shifts work (implementation defined by C spec)
    return (x>>31) | ((unsigned)-x >> 31);
}
```

The first part (`x>>32`) gives you -1 for negative numbers and 0 for 0 or positive numbers.
The second part gives you 1 if x > 0 or equal to INT_MIN, and 0 otherwise.   Or gives you the right final answer.

There's also the canonical `return (x > 0) - (x < 0);`, but unfortunately most compilers will use branches to generate code for that, even though there are no visible branches.  You can try to manually turn it into branchless code as:

```
int sign(int x)
{
    // assumes 32-bit int/unsigned
    return ((unsigned)-x >> 31) - ((unsigned)x >> 31);
}
```

which is arguably better than the above as it doesn't depend on implementation defined behavior, but has a subtle bug in that it will return 0 for INT_MIN.

Comment: This is very nice. You could get away from the INT_MIN bug by putting `x|=x>>1` before the return. INT_MIN is 10000... INT_MIN | INT_MIN>>1 is 11000...  which can be negated safely.

Comment: `-x` has signed-overflow UB on `INT_MIN`.  Casting first, `-(unsigned)x`, would avoid that, and give the same binary result on a 2's complement machine.

Comment: @PeterCordes `-(unsigned)INT_MIN` is `INT_MIN`. `~INT_MIN` is `INT_MAX` and `(unsigned)INT_MAX) + 1` is `INT_MIN`.

Comment: You can avoid the `INT_MIN` bug by doing the negation manually and excluding the addition for `INT_MIN`: `(~x + !!(x^INT_MIN))`, but godbolt shows me this is more instructions than `(x>0)-(x<0)` on every compiler I sampled.

Comment: @BenjaminRiggs: No, `-(unsigned)INT_MIN` is an *`unsigned`* integer with the value `0x80000000` (the correct magnitude) on machines with 32-bit 2's complement `int`, like `0u - INT_MIN`, because it converts INT_MIN to unsigned first, applying range reduction to get `0x80000000u`.  Unary `-` wraps back to the same `unsigned` value.  But `-INT_MIN` has type `int`, and has signed overflow UB. https://godbolt.org/z/7Wzb4sWeG shows the compiler warnings.  In practice many compilers wrap, giving `-2147483648` (with the same bit-pattern), but you need `gcc -fwrapv` to make that safe.

Comment: @PeterCordes `(unsigned) -(unsigned)INT_MIN` is the same as `(unsigned) INT_MIN`, so the bug persists.

Comment: @BenjaminRiggs: Correct, but what bug?  For this particular use-case, `INT_MIN` is negative so `INT_MIN >> 31` will be `-1` (assuming a sane implementation where right-shifts round toward -Inf).  It doesn't matter what you OR that it (on a 2's complement machine at least), so there's no need to generate the wrong unsigned absolute value; it's perfectly ok to OR in `0x80000000u >> 31` = `1`.  The OR trick probably doesn't work on 1's complement machines.

Comment: @BenjaminRiggs: Or are you talking about the subtraction version which does have a problem with `INT_MIN` on 2's complement machines?  I wasn't proposing a fix for that, I was just avoiding UB while doing the same binary operations this code is using.  It basically assumes `-fwrapv`, but doesn't need to since we can use unsigned subtraction / negation.  (Sorry, I didn't re-read the whole answer before replying to your comment, I forgot part of this answer did have an INT_MIN problem other than requiring wrapping.)

Answer (score 1):

```
int sign(int x) {    
    return (x>>31)|(!!x);
}
```

Comment: He is using the bitwise shift operator.  In some languages it is a "Sign-propagating right shift" (such as in JavaScript), which means the sign does not change.  Thus, shifting off ALL bits of a 32-bit float using `x>>31` leaves only the sign. `!!x` converts to true or false (1 or 0), then he bitwise "OR"s them together (combines the bits).

Comment: Right shifting signed integers is undefined behaviour! You need to cast it to an unsigned integer type: `return ((unsigned)x>>31)|(!!x)`

Comment: Not only that, but assuming that `int` is 32 bits is completely non-portable - you can *probably* expect it to be `sizeof (int) * CHAR_BIT` bits.  One thing you can't assume is that negative numbers have a particular coding; sign-magnitude, one's complement and two's complement are well-known possibilities, but C doesn't constrain implementations to be one of those.

Comment: @osvein Sorry, your variant incorrectly returns `1` on all negative values for `x`. This is not, what the original poster wanted.

Comment: @osvein No, it is implementation-defined behavior, as in it can be either arithmetic or logic shift, but it cannot cause the program to crash etc. Casting to unsigned is good practice though. And this answer is questionable at best...

Answer (score 0):

If `s(x)` is a function that returns the sign-bit of `x` (you implemented it by `((unsigned int)x)>>31`), you can combine `s(x)` and `s(-x)` in some way. Here is a "truth table":

> x > 0: s(x) = 0; s(-x) = 1; your function must return 1
>
> x < 0: s(x) = 1; s(-x) = 0; your function must return -1
>
> x = 0: s(x) = 0; s(-x) = 0; your function must return 0

So you can combine them in the following way:

```
s(-x) - s(x)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
int i = -10;
if((i & 1 << 31) == 0x80000000)sign = 0;else sign = 1;
//sign 1 = -ve, sign 0 = -ve
```

Comment: Left shifting data into the sign bit as was done here `(i & 1 << 31)` is explicitly undefined behavior.