# Comparing fractions with struct

Tags: c, struct, comparison, fractions

The function is supposed to compare two fractions that are stored in two structs.

- If fraction L = fraction R return 0
- If L > R return 1
- If R > L return -1

Here is the code I have now:

```
int compare_fractions(Fraction L, Fraction R)
{
    double z = (L.numer/L.denom) - (R.numer/R.denom);
    // THIS CODE IS INCORRECT - FIX IT!  
    if(z == 0)
        return 0;
    else if(z < 0)
        return -1;
    else if(z
        return 1;
}
```

However when I run the following tests I receive 0's with the following comparisons:

```
(1,3) ? (2,3)
(5,6) ? (3,4)
(2,4) ? (1,4)
```

where (1,3) is fraction L and (2,3) is fraction R

Comment: And the test for z equal to zero is bad.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19837576/comparing-floating-point-number-to-zero

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the numerator and denominator are `int`s (or another integer type) then the division is [integer division](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3602827/995714), you'll never get the correct fractional part

Casting it to `double` can correct most of the problem but you'll face the slow divisions and sometimes errors due to floating-point roundings.

You should use multiplication instead. It'll be much faster and you don't need a floating-point division which is very slow on some architectures. This way you don't need to worry about floating-point comparisons either

```
int compare_fractions(Fraction L, Fraction R)
{
    int z = L.numer*R.denom - L.denom*R.numer;
    if (z == 0)
        return 0;
    else if (z > 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return -1;
}
```

Of course you need to make sure that all the denominators are positive, otherwise you need to normalize it (you can use chux's suggestion below). You also need to account for overflow if you values can be large by doing the math in a wider type like

```
long long z = (long long)L.numer*R.denom - L.denom*R.numer
```

If you can lax the requirements a bit to return negative, 0 or positive values for less than, equal or more than case just like `strcmp()` then you can remove the checks for z's value altogether and `return L.numer*R.denom - L.denom*R.numer` directly instead

If you still need to return -1, 0 and 1 then there are several ways to shorten/optimize it like

```
return (z > 0) - (z < 0);
return (z == 0) ? 0 : (z < 0 ? -1 : 1);
return (z >> 31) | (!!z);
```

- [Is there a standard sign function (signum, sgn) in C/C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1903954/995714)
- [Fast sign of integer in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14579920/995714)
- [Branchless code that maps zero, negative, and positive to 0, 1, 2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1610836/995714)

Comment: Normalization suggestion: `int z = ...; if (R.denom < 0) z = -z;  if (L.denom < 0) z = -z;`  Note: downside to only using `int` is integer overflow.  Going to a wider `int` size helps, but is not a great solution either.  But your answer is the right approach.

Comment: @chux Most architectures have widening multiplication so using a wider int type is not much a problem, it's still faster than converting numbers from int to double and then divide

Comment: Agree most architectures have wider integers.  Using `intmax_t` would typically be a safe candidate.  If not, `double` could be used with the same division-less approach you employed.

Answer (score 0):

When you divide an `int` by another `int`, it will first divide them and (because the result must be an `int` as well) rounds the result towards zero. First at this point is it cast into a `double`:

```
int a = 7;
int b = 3;
double c = a / b; // = 2, because 2.333... rounded down is 2, which is
                  //      then cast to a double
```

The solution is to cast either the numerator or the denominator to a `double` before dividing:

```
int a = 7;
int b = 3;
double c = (double)a / b; // = 2.333... because it's cast to a double before
                          //            dividing
//double c = a / (double)b; // this will also work
```

More specifically, if you change one line in your code to this, it should work:

```
double z = ((double)L.numer/L.denom) - ((double)R.numer/R.denom);
```