# How to determine if an integer will fit a variable?

Tags: c++

```
int1_type x = ...;
int2_type y;

if ([check whether the current value of x will fit into y]) {
   y = x;
}
```

Is there a generic way to check if the current value of x will fit into y (eg. long x = 1; char y = x;) when their types depend on platform and/or template specializations?

Comment: Use `sizeof(int1_type) >= sizeof(int2_type)`?

Comment: sizeof(char) < sizeof(long), but long x = 1; will fit char y;

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ But if x = 1, y will be able to hold it even if that equation is not true.

Comment: Are the ints standard built-in types? If so, use `std::numeric_limits`

Comment: long x = some_function_that_might_return_big_number(); char y = x;

Comment: @juanchopanza, someone at ##c++ at freenode gave me this: http://ideone.com/rib5Es - it uses std::numeric_limits yet it still doesn't work properly.

Comment: @TonyD runtime check, clarified the question

Comment: The expression **"y will fit the current value of x"** is rather unclear. Did you mean **"the value of y will fit (into) the type of x"**?

Answer (score 1):

Your intention is to assign it. A lossy assignement on basic type will never corrupt your program so:

```
template<typename T> int sign(T data) {
  return (data>=0) - (data<0);
}

template<typename T, typename K> bool test(T source, K target) {
  target = (K)source;
  return (source == target) && (sign(source)*sign(target)>=0);
}
```

simply write

```
if (test(x,y)) {
 y = x;
}
```

Comment: Is it guaranteed by the standard that it'll never corrupt the program? I know that integer overflows are undefined behavior, isn't lossy assignment that leads to integer overflow a UB too?

Comment: The undefined behaviour is about the new value contained in the "smaller" integer. It states that you cannot do assumption about the new value in the smaller integer after losing data.

Comment: I thought UB can be literally anything. Where does the standard say that I'm ok if I don't assume anything about the new value?

Comment: I've update the answer. There was a problem with int x = - 1 and unsigned long as y type.

Comment: Updated adding function sign() as suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14579920/fast-sign-of-integer-in-c

Comment: This solution doesn't require C++11

Answer (score 1):

```
template<typename T, typename U>
bool will_fit(U u, T t = T())
{
    auto const Tmax = std::numeric_limits<T>::max();
    auto const Tmin = std::numeric_limits<T>::min();

    if (std::numeric_limits<U>::is_signed)
    {
        if (std::numeric_limits<T>::is_signed)
            return u >= (std::intmax_t)Tmin && u <= (std::intmax_t)Tmax;
        return u >= 0 && u <= (std::uintmax_t)Tmax;
    }
    else
        return u <= (std::uintmax_t)Tmax;
}
```

With some [SFINAE tricks](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if), some of those runtime checks can be made into compile time checks, but I'll leave that for you to investigate, if performance is an issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you can be restricted to PODs.

There is CHAR_BIT which holds how many bits in a char.

I guess you could do for unsigned types:

```
if ((x >= 0) &&  (x < pow(2, CHAR_BIT * sizeof y))){
  y = x;
}
```

Comment: Should be `<` instead of `<=`.

Comment: What about negative x?

Answer (score 0):

The expression **`y` will fit the current value of `x`** is rather unclear.

If you meant **the value of `y` will fit (into) the type of `x`**, then you can use this:

```
if (sizeof(int2_type) <= sizeof(int1_type) || (int2_type)(int1_type)y == y)
{
    // the value of y fits into the type of x
}
```

Comment: Interesting approach but you aren't testing the current x value.

Comment: @StefanoBuora: Well, I should have written in the comment "y can fit into **the type of** x", which to my understanding is what OP means. I'll fix that, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This one uses  and  to check ranges and signs of the values:

```
#include <limits>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T> T max_for(T) { return std::numeric_limits<T>::max(); }
template<typename T> T min_for(T) { return std::numeric_limits<T>::min(); }
template<typename T> bool is_signed(T) { return std::is_signed<T>::value; }
template<typename T1, typename T2> bool same_sign(T1, T2) {
    return std::is_signed<T1>::value == std::is_signed<T2>::value; }

template <typename T1, typename T2>
bool fits(T1 src, T2 dst)
{
    auto valid_signed_to_unsigned =
        (is_signed(src) && !is_signed(dst) && src >= 0 && src <= ((max_for(dst) -1) / 2));

    auto valid_unsigned_to_sign =
        (!is_signed(src) && is_signed(dst) && src <= max_for(dst));

    auto valid_same =
        same_sign(src, dst) && src >= min_for(dst) && src <= max_for(dst);

    if (valid_signed_to_unsigned || valid_unsigned_to_sign || valid_same)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work for: int src= -1; unsigned int dst;
The function will return true. (I had some warning for signed/unsigned  missmatch)

Answer (score -2):

Use the numeric limits template to find the maximum, with a helper function for type deduction:

```
#include <limits>

template<typename T> max_for(T) { return std::numeric_limits<T>::max(); }
template<typename T> min_for(T) { return std::numeric_limits<T>::min(); }

if (x >= min_for(y) && x <= max_for(y))
  y = x;   // type of y can accomodate the value x
```

Comment: @lamefun The idea was to demonstrate type deduction. See other answers (e.g. [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26544263/1600898)) for more complete implementations.