# How to set / change the absolute value of variable?

Tags: c, variables, bit-manipulation, sign

Everyone knows the `abs()` function to *get* the absolute value of variables. Is there a similar function or efficient way of setting it ignoring the sign?

**Practical example:**
Force minimum value for motor speed control

```
if (abs(speed) < 50 && speed != 0)
{
    if (speed < 0)
        speed = -50;
    else
        speed = 50;
}
```

I am looking for a standardized function or a clever bit manipulation one-liner.
Wrapping the above if into a function or macro is obvious.

Comment: `speed = (1 - 2*(speed < 0))*50`  will do the inner bit.   The expression `speed < 0` evaluates to `1` if `speed < 0` and `0` otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's basically the [signum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signum_function) function

```
speed = 50*sgn(speed);
```

There's a [standard function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/copysign) for this

```
speed = copysign(50, speed);
```

however this isn't quite efficient for integer types.

The `sgn()` function can be implemented using various other ways that you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1903954/995714)

```
speed = ((speed > 0) - (speed < 0))*50;
```

Comment: More importantly, going via a floating-point type will lose precision from large enough integers.

Comment: @TobySpeight a double-precision type can store exactly all integers up to 2^53, so it'll work well for an `int32_t`

Answer (score 2):

Combining with answers you can find around SO, for example  [Fast sign of integer in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14579920/fast-sign-of-integer-in-c):

```
speed=((speed > 0) - (speed < 0)) * theNewValue;
```

You basically just want to keep the sign, and multiply it by a new norm.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for an integer equivalent of the standard `copysign()` function.

The simplest way to do that is simply to multiply the absolute value of the `magnitude` argument by the sign of the `sign` argument, using one of the standard methods to obtain that:

```
int setabs(int magnitude, int sign)
{
     return magnitude
        * ((magnitude > 0) - (magnitude < 0))
        * ((sign > 0) - (sign < 0));
}
```

Tests to demonstrate:

```
int main()
{
    return
        + (setabs(50, 1) != 50)
        + (setabs(50, 0) != 0)
        + (setabs(50, -1) != -50)
        + (setabs(-50, 1) != 50)
        + (setabs(-50, 0) != 0)
        + (setabs(-50, -1) != -50);
}
```

If multiplications are expensive for you, then we can use subtraction of two booleans to make a slightly cheaper version (passing the same set of tests):

```
int setabs(int magnitude, int sign)
{
    return magnitude
        * ((magnitude > 0 == sign >= 0) - (magnitude > 0 == sign <= 0));
}
```

Any bit-manipulation techniques will depend on which representation is used by your platform for negative integers (sign-magnitude, one's-complement, two's-complement, ...), and will require casting the arguments to unsigned types (or rely on undefined behaviour).

Comment: If you want 0 to be considered "positive" for the sign, modify the tests and swap `>` with `>=`.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your platform.  Since you haven't said what system you're targeting, I'm going to assume your integers use sign+magnitude representation.  ;-)

```
int setabs(int sign, int magnitude)
{
    static const unsigned mask =- 0^0;
    assert(mask); // in case it's used on weird (two's complement) systems
    return (int)((unsigned)sign&mask | (unsigned)magnitude&~mask);
}
```

You can then write

```
speed = setabs(speed, 50);
```

Comment: You must have some coding error here. `assert(mask);` is like `assert(0);`  Perhaps `- 0` was to be `~ 0`?  Maybe use `mask = UINT_MAX - INT_MAX;`

Comment: I am not trying to say `-0` and `~0` are the same.  Yet `unsigned mask =- 0^0;` is zero with 2's complement - the far most common.  This leads to `assert(mask);` failing to assert and causing a compile time failure.

Comment: Yes, that's why we assert - to make sure this isn't run on a two's complement system, as written in the comment.

Comment: Try running the code. - on a 2's complement machine.

Comment: Sleep well my friend,  Review it another day.

Comment: Just had chance to try it on a 2's-complement machine, and it successfully aborts for me.  It's only a run-time failure, but if we used C++, we could `static_assert` the same thing to get compile-time failure (which is obviously better).  Or we could fake it with the array dimension trick that I vaguely remember seeing once.

Comment: Note that C has `static_assert` since C11.