# Find the amount of changes in the sign of number in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, numbers, sign

Basically, I have an array given of "x" numbers and I have to output the amount of how many times the sign changed in the numbers of the array.

For example array is:
2 -4 5 6 7 -2 5 -7

The output should be 5. Why? Because the sign changes first time at -4, second time at 5, third time at -2, fourth time at 5 and last time at -7. Total 5 times.

So, I have this so far but that doesn't work perfectly:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int a[50],n,cs=0,ha=0;



cin >> n;
for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    cin >> a[i];
}
for (int j=1;j<=n;j++)
{
    if(a[j]<0 && a[j-1]>0)
    cs++;
    else if(a[j]>0 && a[j-1]<0)
    cs++;
}
cout << cs << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Please help!

Comment: "Please help"? What's not working?  What line is giving a problem? what's the problem with your expected output? whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: Accessing `a[n]` is undefined behaviour.

Comment: My problem is that my code is not working correctly, it's displaying an output incorrect to the one expected.

Comment: You have to take a value of `0` into account. You should, for example, consider it to be positive. Then, change `>0` to `>=0` to handle this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you're running into uninitialized memory, which is causing undefined behaviour. You initialize `a[0]` through `a[n-1]` in your input loop and then read from `a[0]` (with j=1 and `a[j-1]`) to `a[n]` (j=n and `a[j]`) in your calculation loop.

Simply change it to `j < n`.

Comment: Changing j<=n to j<n pretty much fixed it. It seems to be working perfectly now :O

Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 2):

If STL is an option for you, you can use `std::adjacent_find`. This is how you would use it in a complete program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> v { 1 , 3, -5, 8, -9, -10, 4 };

    auto signSwitch = [] (int x, int y) { return (abs(x) == x) ^ (abs(y) == y); };

    int cnt = 0;
    auto i = adjacent_find(begin(v), end(v), signSwitch);
    while (i != end(v))
    {
        cnt++;
        i = adjacent_find(i + 1, end(v), signSwitch);
    }

    cout << cnt;
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend taking the product. Consider two large integers; they will overflow. I'd use something like `(x >= 0) != (y >= 0)`.

Comment: Interesting application of `adjacent_find`.

Comment: @leemes: true. That's just the quickest thing that came up to my mind. I never remember if `sgn()` is standard.

Comment: @AndyProwl [It doesn't seem like there is one.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903954/is-there-a-standard-sign-function-signum-sgn-in-c-c)

Answer (score 1):

Your second loop should terminate at `j < n`.

Answer (score 1):

On your second for loop you should not have j go to <=. it should just be

```
 for (int j=1;j<n;j++)
```