# write it in one line: add or reduce by a sign of a number

Tags: c++

```
float f = -0.050000;
```

I want to do the next rules:

```
if (f < 0) f -= 0.2;
else       f += 0.2;
```

there is an option to do it by one line?

Comment: use the ternary operator `?`

Comment: use 'f += std::sgn(f)*0.2;'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a modified version of C++ branchless [signum](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1903954/335858) function for this:

```
f += 0.2 * ((0<=f)-(f<0));
```

The expression

```
(0<=f)-(f<0)
```

evaluates to `-1` when `f` is less than zero, to `1` when `f` is greater than or equal to zero.

Answer (score 4):

If [copysign](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/copysign) or an equivalent is available, then

```
f += copysign(0.2,f);
```

is likely to be the fastest with modern computers because it avoids branching.  Given the length of processing pipelines on modern CPUs, [a branch misprediction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_misprediction) can easily cost several cycles

Answer (score 3):

You could do:

```
f += (f < 0) ? -0.2 : +0.2;
```

Answer (score 1):

How about you use the conditional operator?

```
f += (f < 0) ? -0.2f : 0.2f;
```