# How to sort an Array of signed numbers in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, sorting, nsarray

This may be a simple question, but i don't know the way of doing sorting of array of signed integer values.

My array before sorting,

```
pointsAry (-2,-7,-5,0,-3,2,-1,-4,1,3,-6)
```

After using

```
NSArray * sortedArray = [pointsAry sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id str1, id str2){
        return [(NSString *)str1 compare:(NSString *)str2 options:NSNumericSearch];
    }];
```

Result

```
sortedArray : (-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6,-7,0,1,2,3)
```

for signed values the sortedArray format is not correct, so i need like

```
(-7,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3)
```

How to sort like above format ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [pointsAry sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(NSString *str1, NSString *str2){
    return [@([str1 intValue]) compare:@([str2 intValue])];
}];
```

Comment: Why box those in an `NSNumber`? Comparing `integerValue`s with the `<` operator is good enough.

Comment: @H2CO3 The comparator has to return an `NSComparisonResult`. Boxing is just the shortest way to reuse `compare:`.

Comment: @H2CO3 Just subtracting the values would be nice if not only 0 and ±1 would be allowed as return values.

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist There's no easy way to clamp the difference to -1 .. 1 without a temporary variable.

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist It is, but this `NSComparisonResult` system Cocoa (Touch) enforces is insane: comparators are expected to return exactly -1, 0 or +1.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe AFAIK the APIs that use the comparison results all work fine with int values outside the -1 to 1 range. That is of course not documented behavior

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist Not documented == Not possible to use in production code.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe: meaning of `@`before `intValue` in `return` statement?

Comment: @preetam I don't understand your question. There's no @ before `intValue`. If you mean the @ before the parenthesis: That's shorthand to box the `int` values into `NSNumber`s.

Answer (score 5):

The following comparator avoids the creation of temporary `NSNumber` objects:

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [pointsAry sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSString *str1, NSString *str2) {
    return my_int_compare([str1 intValue], [str2 intValue]);
}];
```

where

```
static inline int my_int_compare(int x, int y) { return (x > y) - (x < y); }
```

is a helper function that compares two integers and returns -1, 0, or +1 (as required
for a comparator method), using the technique from

- [Is there a standard sign function (signum, sgn) in C/C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903954/is-there-a-standard-sign-function-signum-sgn-in-c-c).

Of course the problem only arises because the array contains `NSString` objects.
Using `NSNumber`s would be the better solution.

Using the `NSNumericSearch` option does not help because it does not treat the minus
sign as part of the number.

Comment: Sneaky. +1, even though I'm not sure if I like the obfuscation introduced by calculating the return value.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe: Thanks for the feedback. Perhaps it is less obfuscate if the calculation of the sign is moved into a separate function (answer edited).

Comment: There remains one caveat: Calculating the difference `[str1 intValue] - [str2 intValue]` might overflow which is undefined behavior in C. Avoiding this by using `return (a > b) - (a < b);` where `a` and `b` are just the int values of the parameters would remove the bug, yet also the readability.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe: You are right! So answer edited again: No bug (hopefully) and medium readability.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"P3",@"P1",@"P4",@"P10", nil];
    NSMutableArray *num=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for(int i=0;i<array.count;i++)
    {
        NSString *str=array[i];
       [num addObject: [str substringFromIndex:1]];
    }



    NSArray *sortedArray = [num sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(NSString *str1, NSString *str2){
        return [@([str1 intValue]) compare:@([str2 intValue])];
    }];
    [array removeAllObjects];
    for(int i=0;i<sortedArray.count;i++)
    {
        NSString *newString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"P%@",sortedArray[i]];


        [array addObject:newString];
    }
```

It's work for me