# How can this function be optimized

Tags: math, optimization, integer

Hi I have created this function which be be used to separate a game world into chunks.
Each chunk is 32 blocks in size. 
This formula calculates the start coordinate of a given chunk number of a given world coordinate. It works good but I think it is possible to optimize it but I have no idea. It is important that the formula works with negative numbers.

```
    static int wrld2chnk(int wrld)
    {
        if (wrld % 32 != 0)
        {
            if (wrld < 0)
                wrld -= (32 + wrld % 32);
            else
                wrld -= wrld % 32;
        }
        return wrld;
    }
```

// these are example values which can be used to validate the result. The first value in each rpw is the method input, the second is the output:

```
    (0, 0);
    (31, 0);
    (32, 32);
    (33, 32);
    (-1, -32);
    (-31, -32);
    (-32, -32);
    (-33, -64);
    (-34, -64);
    (-64, -64);
    (-70, -96);
```

Comment: That's the same as just `wrld & -32`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, the first `if` can clearly go. The positive case works fine for zero, too:

```
static int wrld2chnk(int wrld)
{
    if (wrld < 0)
        wrld -= (32 + wrld % 32);
    else
        wrld -= wrld % 32;
    return wrld;
}
```

But it can be much simpler. You're working around the fact that `%` cares about the sign. Rounding down to a multiple of a power of two is much easier, just use bitwise AND with the negative of the power of 2 that you're rounding down to:

```
static int wrld2chnk(int wrld)
{
    return wrld & -32;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about now guys..??

```
if(wrld>0)
wrld = (wrld/32)*32;
else
wrld = ((wrld/32)-1)*32
```

Comment: OP has `wrld -= wrld % 32` for that case. How is this an improvement?

Comment: @DSM it doesn't, it rounds the wrong way for negative numbers, so for example it turns -1 into 0 instead of -32

Comment: @harold: ah, I see.  I was fooled by precedence when I tried it at the Python console.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my proposal:

```
int wrld2chnk (int wrld)
{
  return sgn(wrld)*32*((32*(sgn(wrld)==-1)+abs(wrld))/32);
}
```

Where `sgn(x)` is:

```
#define sgn(x) (((x)>=0)?1:-1)
```

Although if you are concerned about the ternary operator (I just love it), here you have some alternative implementations for `sgn()`:
[Is there a standard sign function (signum, sgn) in C/C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903954/is-there-a-standard-sign-function-signum-sgn-in-c-c)