# Safe Floating Point Division

Tags: c, floating-point, division, divide-by-zero, c89

I have some places in my code where I want to assure that a division of 2 arbitrary floating point numbers (32 bit single precision) won't overflow. The target/compiler does not guarantee (explicitly enough) nice handling of -INF/INF and (does not fully guarantees IEEE 754 for the exceptional values - (possibly undefined) - and target might change). Also I cannot make save assumtions on the inputs for this few special places and I am bound to C90 standard libraries.

I have read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) but to be honest, I am a little bit lost.

So... I want to ask the community, if the following piece of code would do the trick, and if there are better/faster/exacter/correcter ways to do it:

```
#define SIGN_F(val) ((val >= 0.0f)? 1.0f : -1.0f)

float32_t safedivf(float32_t num, float32_t denum)
{
   const float32_t abs_denum = fabs(denum);
   if((abs_denum < 1.0f) && ((abs_denum * FLT_MAX) <= (float32_t)fabs(num))
       return SIGN_F(denum) * SIGN_F(num) * FLT_MAX;
   else
       return num / denum;
}
```

---

Edit: Changed `((abs_denum * FLT_MAX) < (float32_t)fabs(num))` to `((abs_denum * FLT_MAX) <= (float32_t)fabs(num))` as recommeded by Pascal Cuoq.

Comment: Goldberg's paper loses most people on a first reading, it is a dreadful resource for a beginner learning how to use f-p numbers and arithmetic.  It is targeted at people designing software and hardware for implementing f-p numbers and algorithms.  You would have been better starting at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point

Comment: Surely better to ask forgiveness than permission

Comment: `SIGN_F(val)` does not correctly extract the sign of `-0.0`, so `1.0 / -0.0` is going to end up as `+FLT_MAX`. You may or may not mind. If you aren't sure of IEEE 754, perhaps you cannot be sure of `copysign` either, but if it is there you might as well use it.

Comment: @PascalCuoq Ah your are right. Is there any chance to extract the sign of a value that is possibly -0.0f with the set of functions specified in C89/90 without trying do interfere with the floating point bit patterns? Correct me if I renember wrong: -0.0 compares exact like 0.0?

Comment: @MarkA. Yes, for `==`, `>`, etc., the signed zeroes are undistinguishable. You must 1- use `copysign`, or 2- access the representation through a `union`, or 3- divide by it and cause the very overflow that you are trying to avoid. That leaves you with solution 2-.

Comment: @PascalCuoq As I thought. I fear I will be harder to get guarantees on the bit patterns then on the exceptional value behavior. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I don't understand your comment.

Comment: Attempt to perform the divide. If it fails, detect that failure and react accordingly. Trying to predict the failure ahead of time is just as hard, in fact probably harder, than going ahead and performing the division.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Ah. Thanks for the input. I this special case, we don't trust the target very much to trap the error and that I have the possibility to recover from - as the specifications below the C-language level are a little bit in a flow. I have to assume that an overflow will lead to undefined bahavior, therefore I have to ask for permission. :-)

Comment: @Pascal Cuoq  A good `atan2f(y,x)` distinguishes between `+0.0` and `-0.0` with `atan2f(zero, -1.0)` which will return `+pi` or `-pi` depending on `+0`, `-0`.

Comment: instead of defining `SIGN_F` you can use `signbit` or `copysign` [Is there a standard sign function (signum, sgn) in C/C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1903954/995714)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `((abs_denum * FLT_MAX) < (float32_t)fabs(num)`, the product `abs_denum * FLT_MAX` may round down and end up equal to `fabs(num)`. This does not mean that `num / denum` is not mathematically larger than `FLT_MAX`, and you should be worried that it might happen to cause the overflow that you want to avoid. You had better replace this `<` by `<=`.

---

For an alternative solution, if a `double` type is available and is wider than `float`, it may be more economical to compute `(double)num/(double)denum`. If `float` is binary32ish and `double` is binary64ish, the only way the `double` division can overflow is if `denum` is (a) zero (and if `denum` is a zero your code is also problematic).

```
double dbl_res = (double)num/(double)denum;
float res = dbl_res < -FLT_MAX ? -FLT_MAX : dbl_res > FLT_MAX ? FLT_MAX : (float)dbl_res;
```

Comment: Can you please point out, where/if my (corrected) code is problematic in the case of 0.0, besides the sign-issue?

Comment: @MarkA. I was only referring to the sign issue.

Comment: Downvoter, any explanation why you find this answer particularly bad?

Comment: I am also surprised, because this solution - together with some -0.0 sign detector seemed to be the one to go for us. I can't see any further pitfalls, given that our floats and doubles hold the condition. But this can be assured by preprocessor. What is the reason for downvote?

Comment: Hm... Seems that there is nothing additional to say for the downvote... if you also haven't a idea in meanwhile why there might be a problem. I would go for your answer.

Comment: @MarkA. The downvote may come from someone in the “floating-point results are random” school of thought, to whom the idea of discussing the nuance between `<` and `<=`, instead of comparing “up to epsilon”, whatever that means in this case (add epsilon or subtract it? what value of epsilon?), might be anathema.

Comment: @MarkA. Why might I be right when I suggest a simple, non-epsilon-involving solution? I started working on the art of predicting what a C program using floating-point can do in 2009 (http://hisseo.saclay.inria.fr/index.html ), and I haven't really stopped since.

Answer (score 4):

You may try to extract the exponents and the mantissas of num and denum, and make sure that condition:

```
((exp(num) - exp (denum)) > max_exp) &&  (mantissa(num) >= mantissa(denum))
```

And according to the sign of the inputs, generate the corresponding INF.

Comment: Not sure if that's the exactly right formula, but it's the right approach.

Comment: I think it is correct as long as you use round to nearest mode.

Comment: If `exp(num) - exp(denum)` is significantly larger than `max_exp`, the values of the mantissa are irrelevant and overflow still occurs.  Also the exponent of `(0.0)` is typically `0` and then `num == 0` or `denum == 0` need special handling.

Answer (score 1):

Carefully work with `num, denom` when the quotient is near `FLT_MAX`.

The following uses tests inspired by OP but stays away from results near `FLT_MAX`.  As @Pascal Cuoq points out that rounding may just push the result over the edge.  Instead it uses thresholds of `FLT_MAX/FLT_RADIX` and `FLT_MAX*FLT_RADIX`.

By scaling with `FLT_RADIX`, typically 2, code should always get exact results.  Rounding under any rounding mode is not expected to infect the result.

In terms of speed, the "happy path", that is, when results certainly do not overflow should be a speedy calculation.  Still need to do unit testing, but the comments should provide the gist of this approach.

```
static int SD_Sign(float x) {
  if (x > 0.0f)
    return 1;
  if (x < 0.0f)
    return -1;
  if (atan2f(x, -1.0f) > 0.0f)
    return 1;
  return -1;
}

static float SD_Overflow(float num, float denom) {
  return SD_Sign(num) * SD_Sign(denom) * FLT_MAX;
}

float safedivf(float num, float denom) {
  float abs_denom = fabsf(denom);
  // If |quotient| > |num|
  if (abs_denom < 1.0f) {
    float abs_num = fabsf(num);
    // If |num/denom| > FLT_MAX/2 --> quotient is very large or overflows
    // This computation is safe from rounding and overflow.
    if (abs_num > FLT_MAX / FLT_RADIX * abs_denom) {
      // If |num/denom| >= FLT_MAX*2 --> overflow
      // This also catches denom == 0.0
      if (abs_num / FLT_RADIX >= FLT_MAX * abs_denom) {
        return SD_Overflow(num, denom);
      }
      // At this point, quotient must be in or near range FLT_MAX/2 to FLT_MAX*2
      // Scale parameters so quotient is a FLT_RADIX * FLT_RADIX factor smaller.
      if (abs_num > 1.0) {
        abs_num /= FLT_RADIX * FLT_RADIX;
      } else {
        abs_denom *= FLT_RADIX * FLT_RADIX;
      }
      float quotient = abs_num / abs_denom;
      if (quotient > FLT_MAX / (FLT_RADIX * FLT_RADIX)) {
        return SD_Overflow(num, denom);
      }
    }
  }
  return num / denom;
}
```

The `SIGN_F()` needs to consider in `denum` is `+0.0` or `-0.0`.  Various methods mentioned by @Pascal Cuoq in a comment:

1. `copysign()` or `signbit()`
2. Use a union

Additional, some functions, when well implemented, differentiate on +/- zero like `atan2f(zero, -1.0)` and `sprintf(buffer, "%+f", zero)`.

Note: Used `float` vs. `float32_t` for simplicity.
Note: Maybe use `fabsf()` rather than `fabs()`.
Minor: Suggest `denom` (denominator) in lieu of `denum`.

Comment: Wikipedia should have a “list of C functions that distinguish +0.0 and -0.0”.

Comment: Thank you for this elaborate answer. The atan2-trick is clever. Some remarks from me:
--- I think the math.h xxxf functions like fabsf are first introduced with C99. I'm am sure about atan2f regarding this. Same holds for copysign and signbit.
--- For the union solution, I will go for this for final optimizations, when for the final compiler settings I can get the assured the bit pattern by our compiler ventor.
--- For our application we have strict runtime guarantees to give so we are in an "average case == worst case" design, whereever the code becomes simpler. So we have no "happy path".

Comment: @Mark A. For alternate ways to distinguish +0.0 from -0.0, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25332133/what-operations-and-functions-on-0-0-and-0-0-give-different-arithmetic-results.  Add solutions there if you find another.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the corner cases with rounding and what not, you could massage the exponent on the divisor -- with frexp() and ldexp() -- and worry about whether the result can be scaled back without overflow.  Or frexp() both arguments, and do the exponenent work by hand.