# How to check if a double variable is a signed zero?

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation

How do I check if my variable `double x` is equal to -0.0?

Comment: @IlyaKogan Well not never, right? Just not reliably. If I did `0.0 == 0.0` it would evaluate to true, right?

Comment: Use [`std::signbit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/signbit) and ordinary comparison with `0`?

Comment: @IlyaKogan: Nonsense.

Comment: @Will: No, that won't work.  You need a `reinterpret_cast` (to do that in C requires casting pointers).  But why would C be lacking `signbit`?

Comment: You may find ["What operations and functions on +0.0 and -0.0 give different arithmetic results?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25332133/what-operations-and-functions-on-0-0-and-0-0-give-different-arithmetic-results) useful.

Comment: @Will I guess you are thinking of `*(int64_t *)&x`, rather than `(int64_t)x`

Comment: @Will: Did you actually test on negative zero, or just some other negative values?

Comment: @Will: Your code FAILS.  Demo: http://rextester.com/PQQUE83634  Same results on clang and gcc, and in both C and C++ modes.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Of course `*(int64_t *)&x` would violate strict aliasing.  The library function is definitely the way to go.

Comment: @Will: In fact, it doesn't distinguish sign of any number with magnitude less than 1: http://rextester.com/CSDV23001

Comment: @Will the C standard requires that floating point zero and negative zero both become `+0` after doing `(int64_t)x` . (In fact 2's complement systems, which most of us probably have, do not even have negative zero for integer types).  I'd guess your example that "works as-is" actually casts some extremely small negative but non-zero example.

Comment: @Will: Why?  Conversion to integer truncates toward zero.  I'll say it again: You need a reinterpret_cast here, not a conversion.