# Is floating point multiplication by zero guaranteed to produce zero?

Tags: c++, c, floating-point

I understand floating point has rounding errors, but I'm wondering if there are certain situations where the error does not apply, such as multiplication by zero .

Does zero times any number = zero for all floating points ?

Comment: Apart from special values like NaN, Infinity or -Infinity, you are correct to assume that any normal number multiplied by exact zero produces exactly zero.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

False:

```
0f * NAN == NAN
0f * INFINITY == NAN
```

and ...

```
0f * -1f == -0f (negative 0f), with 0f == -0f :-)
```

(on Intel, VC++, and probably on any platform that uses IEEE 754-1985 floating points)

Example on [ideone](http://ideone.com/L6MQlQ) (that uses GCC on some Intel compatible platform probably)

Comment: Yes, this is guaranteed on any system that conforms to IEEE-754 (but to be perfectly clear: –0 is still "zero").

Comment: @StephenCanon It is still `"0"` in the sense that `0f == -0f`, but for example if you multiply `-0f * INFINITY` and print the result, you obtain `-NaN`, so it is still `0` but its sign can be used/extracted. http://ideone.com/L6MQlQ

Comment: The signbit of a NaN has no meaning, so there's actually no such thing as `–NaN`, nor is `–0 * inf` guaranteed to produce "`–NaN`" (it could produce any quiet NaN value).  The signbit of `–0` can be extracted by other means, however.

Comment: @StephenCanon Exactly for this reason I wrote `**and print the result**, you obtain"`, the printed result of that operation on GCC on Intel is... :-)

Comment: You can determine the sign of `0` by inverting it: `1./0.` => `Infinity` and `1./-0.` => `-Infinity`.  Also beware of the `f` number suffix: it specifies `float` values, not `double`.

Comment: @chqrlie  [Various ways to differentiate -0.0 and +0.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25332133/what-operations-and-functions-on-0-0-and-0-0-give-different-arithmetic-results)

Answer (score 4):

In addition to [@xanatos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30242209/2410359) fine answer, consider some of OP's middle-of-the-post concerns:

> I'm wondering if there are certain situations where the (rounding) error does not apply

Candidates include `some_double_y = some_double_x * 1.0` and `some_double_y = some_double_x + 0.0` may never incur a rounding error.

Yet even those are suspect due to a compiler may evaluate `double` at higher precision considering the `FLT_EVAL_METHOD == 2` where "evaluate all operations and constants to the range and precision of the `long double` type."  In that case, an intermediate `some_double_x` may exist as a `long double` differing from an apparent `double` value of `0.0` or `1.0`.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following "an intermediate some_double_x may exist as a long double differing from an apparent double value of 0.0 or 1.0". If some_double_x is a double variable, I understand this means it could be cast to a long double, added zero / multiplied by one (which should be no-op, right?), and then cast back to double. Are you saying that casting to higher precision and back could cause rounding errors?

Comment: @Jaan It is not a _casting_ nor _rounding_ issue.  With `double x = some_small_double(); if (x / 1.0e300) ...` may or may not take the `if()` path.  The `x / 1.0e300` calculated using `double` math is certainly +/-0.0. `x / 1.0e300` calculated using `long double` math (even though the operands are both `double`) could be a non-zero number.

Comment: @Jaan "added zero / multiplied by one (which should be no-op, right?)" --> Not always.  `-0.0` differs from adding zero.  `-0.0 + 0.0` usually has a sum of `+0.0`.  [Sometimes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25332133/2410359) that difference is important.  I _think_ `*1` is usually a no-op, but if a no-op, why code it?

Comment: OK, thanks for clarifying. I used "casting" for the converting of the floating-point number to another floating-point type, although in these cases it is not required by the language, I don't know what the correct term is. Your post seems to say that some_double_y = some_double_x * 1.0 and some_double_y = some_double_x + 0.0 are sometimes not no-ops because of the compiler evaluating double at higher precision and I wondered how that can be. But now I understand that that's actually not the case.

Comment: May I where the guarantees `some_double_y = some_double_x * 1.0` and `some_double_y = some_double_x + 0.0` are given? Are they given by IEEE-754 or at the instruction set level or at the compiler/interpreter level?

Comment: @ShenZhuoran [Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30242196/is-floating-point-multiplication-by-zero-guaranteed-to-produce-zero/30247953?noredirect=1#comment136158969_30247953) unclear.  Perhaps post a _question_?