# double variable type in c: (negative)0 is not equal to 0

Tags: c, numbers, double, zero

why is there a negative 0.000?

and why is it not equal to 0.000?

Comment: Read about [signed zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero). For the second question, they should be equal. Please show some code where you think they are exhibiting unequal behaviour.

Comment: Re the second question. See http://ideone.com/w7ozc2.

Comment: I can see the IEEE-754 rationale but it's still a bit of a hack. Separate ±1/∞ representations for underflow would seem more natural to me but presumably they would not sufficiently affect the results of actual numerical methods to warrant the silicon space.

Answer (score 2):

The concept of positive and negative zero is a feature of IEEE 754 floating point formats.    There is no requirement that a C implementation will use IEEE floating point formats although, in practice, it is reasonably common.

Even with C implementations that use IEEE floating point formats, positive and negative zero will always compare equal, when using numerical comparisons (such as the `==` operator).   The only way to detect or work with positive and negative zeros on such implementations is to use functions like `copysign()` and `signbit()`  (declared in `<math.h>`).

Answer (score 0):

> why is there a negative 0.000?

This may help a bit
[What operations and functions on +0.0 and -0.0 give different arithmetic results?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25332133/2410359)

> why is it (negative 0.000) not equal to 0.000?

This is a common mis-conclusion.  Reveiw the following:

```
double a = 1e-10;
double b = -2e-20;
printf("a:%f b:%f\n", a, b);
printf("a==b? %d\n", a == b);
printf("a:%e b:%e\n", a, b);

double z = 0.0;
double nz = -0.0;
printf("n:%f nz:%f\n", z, nz);
printf("n==nz? %d\n", z == nz);
```

Output

```
a:0.000000 b:-0.000000   // a and b appear to be 0.0 and -0.0
a==b? 0                  // not same value
a:1.000000e-10 b:-2.000000e-20

n:0.000000 nz:-0.000000  // n and nz appear to be 0.0 and -0.0
n==nz? 1                 // same value
```