# Skipping "test for zero" checks in IEEE 754

Tags: c, ieee-754

I read this in a popular book about computer graphics,

> There are many numeric computations that become much simpler if the programmer takes advantage of the IEEE rules. For example, consider the expression:
>
> a = 1  / (1/b + 1/c)
>
> Such expressions arise with resistors and lenses. If divide-by-zero resulted in a program crash (as was true in many systems before IEEE floating-point), then two if statements would be required to check for small or zero values of b or c. Instead, with IEEE floating-point, if b or c is zero, we will get a zero value for a as desired.

But what about the case where `b=+0` and `c=-0`? Then `a=1/inf-inf=nan`. Is the book wrong about this optimizations, or have I misunderstood something? It seems like we'll still need at least one check for the signs of b & c rather than no checks at all.

**Edit**
One suggestion in the comments was just to do a post-check for NaN. Is that the idiomatic way to "take advantage" of these number type?

```
bool is_nan(float x) { return x != x; }

float optic_thing(float b, float c) {
  float result = 1.0f / (1.0f/b + 1.0f/c);
  if (is_nan(result)) result = 0;
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't a simple postcheck for NaN suffice?

Comment: Likely I'm missing something, but it's unclear why the above statement would be true. If either b or c is zero, then this expression becomes 1/infinity, which is not zero.

Comment: You would need *three* checks of 0 for your expression if `b` or `c` can be negative. Because `1/b + 1/c` will be `0` if `b == -c`

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth But that is zero.

Comment: @2501: is it? If so, then I've just forgotten my 754 rules ;)

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Well it's just math logic, number/inf is zero, but inf-inf isn't defined. Although 1/0 isn't defined either but 754 gives inf.

Comment: @2501: I'd argue it's not logic - 1/inf means no more or less than inf-inf - it means whatever you define it to mean.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Well in math, if you obtain an inf in a sensible way, like using limits, 1/inf is zero.

Comment: IMHO the question boils down to: "what is the fastest way to divide by zero?"

Comment: @wildplasser as you feel, but my intention was to shake out any potential misunderstands, I don't really care about division by zero, I care about understanding IEEE 754.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But what about the case where `b=+0` and `c=-0`?

Convert `-0.0` to `+0.0` without branching by adding `0.0`.

```
int main(void) {
  double b = +0.0;
  double c = -0.0;
  printf("%e\n", b);
  printf("%e\n", c);
  printf("%e\n", 1.0/(1.0/b + 1.0/c));
  b += 0.0;
  c += 0.0;
  printf("%e\n", 1.0/(1.0/b + 1.0/c));
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
0.000000e+00
-0.000000e+00
nan
0.000000e+00
```

---

[Edit] On the other hand, any values near `0.0`, but not `0.0`, are likely numeric artifacts and not accurate *resistance* values.  The above still has trouble with *tiny* value pairs like `b = DBL_TRUE_MIN; c = -b;`  The issue is `1.0/tiny` --> `Infinity` and `+Infinity + -Infinity` --> `NAN`.  Could resort to either using wider floating point for the quotient calculation or narrow the operands.

```
  b += 0.0;
  c += 0.0;
  printf("%Le\n", 1.0/(1.0L/b + 1.0L/c));

  // Lose some precision, but we are talking about real resistors/lenses here.
  b = (float) b + 0.0f;
  c = (float) c + 0.0f;
  printf("%e\n", 1.0/(1.0/b + 1.0/c));
```

Comment: Adding +zero is indeed the canonical way of "cleaning up" undesired instances of -zero. It can also be combined with multiplication if necessary, e.g. `fma (a, b, +0.0)`. Of course this all assumes that one works with a compiler (and compiler switches) that respect proper IEEE-754 behavior in the first place (i.e. doesn't optimize out additions involving zero).

Comment: @njuffa True about "respect proper IEEE-754".  Fortunately OP's post is tagged and titled IEEE 754.  BTW: You may enjoy [+0.0 and -0.0 give different arithmetic results](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25332133/2410359) which is somewhat the opposite of what OP is trying to do.

Comment: I am apparently aware of the question and your answer (now community wiki), because I see that I upvoted the answer. Since I didn't comment or edit the answer I assume that I was unable to think of an example not already mentioned.