# Why does fmax(a, b) return the smaller (negative) zero and how to cleanly workaround it?

Tags: c, math, floating-point

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main () {
    float a = 0.0, b = -0.0;
    printf("fmax(%f, %f) = %f\n", a, b, fmax(a, b));
}
```

I get the following result:

```
gcc f.c -o f -lm
./f
fmax(0.000000, -0.000000) = -0.000000
```

This (mis)behavior is not documented in the fmax man page. Is there a reasonable explanation for it? And is there a clean (concise) workaround? Also, if both are -0.0, I would like to get -0.0 as the max.

Comment: cannot reproduce with gcc 4.9.4. I get 0.000000. Have you tried swapping `a` and `b` values? swapping values gives me `-0.0000000` BTW.

Comment: no-repro on gcc 5.4.0 either.

Comment: +0 and -0 compare equal in IEEE-754, so this implementation is probably just picking an arbitrary argument as its output.

Comment: I'm using gcc 5.4.0 (64-bit).

Comment: MSVC reports `0.000000` no matter which way round.

Comment: @weathervane I'd like to have a robust conversation with the team that decided on that.

Comment: @Bathsheba you mean the team should not have written code to make `+0.000000` greater than `-0.000000`, thus avoiding questions like this?

Comment: I mean the first argument should be returned in the case of equality. I wish that made it into the C and C++ standards.

Comment: @Bathsheba if they are truly **identical** as distinct from **same value**.

Comment: @Bathsheba I do not understand why it matters *which* argument is returned if their values are equal. Sounds like nonsense to me.

Comment: @WeatherVane Try `atan2(+0.0, -1.0)` vs. `atan2(-0.0, -1.0)` for a candidate difference. Not specified to be different by C, but by other various FP standards.

Comment: @chux yes, `atan2` uses the arguments' sign to determine the quadrant. Similarly `atan2(-0.0, +1.0)` returns `-0.000000` and this is the only way I have found so far to obtain the "minus zero" value, apart from assigning it directly as in the question.

Comment: @WeatherVane "... only way I have found so far to obtain the "minus zero" value" might make for an interesting post for terse alternatives.  `strtod("-0",...)` should work too.  Maybe `1/log(0)` or `-DBL_TRUE_MIN/256` or `...`?

Comment: @chux `scanf` too, but `-1.0 - -1.0` does not. If a subtraction did, would it make the `atan2` you mention more useful?

Comment: Can someone explain the purpose of a negative zero?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "problem" is that `a == b`. The sign doesn't matter because mantissa (sign put aside) is purely 0. I get `0x80000000` vs `0`

So `fmax` just checks if `a < b` or `b < a` (depending on the implementation), and both are false, so either answer is a potential match.

On my gcc version I get `fmax(0.0,-0.0)` at `0.0`, but `fmax(-0.0,0.0)` is `-0.0`.

My attempt at a full workaround, using `memcmp` to compare data binary wise in the case of a 0 result.

Even better as suggested, using `signbit` which tests if number has negative bit set (regardless of the value):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

float my_fmax(float a,float b)
{
   float result = fmax(a,b);
   if ((result==0) && (a==b))
   {
       /* equal values and both zero
          the only case of potential wrong selection of the negative 
          value. Only in that case, we tamper with the result of fmax,
          and just return a unless a has negative bit set */

       result = signbit(a) ? b : a;
   }
   return result;
}

int main () {
    float a = -0.0, b = 0.0;

    printf("fmax(%f, %f) = %f\n", a,b, my_fmax(a, b));
    a = 0.0;
    printf("fmax(%f, %f) = %f\n", a,b, my_fmax(a, b));
    a = b = -0.0;
    printf("fmax(%f, %f) = %f\n", a,b, my_fmax(a, b));
    a = 1.0;
    printf("fmax(%f, %f) = %f\n", a,b, my_fmax(a, b));
    a = -1.0;
    printf("fmax(%f, %f) = %f\n", a,b, my_fmax(a, b));
    b = 0.0;
    printf("fmax(%f, %f) = %f\n", a,b, my_fmax(a, b));
}
```

result (I think I covered all the cases):

```
fmax(-0.000000, 0.000000) = 0.000000
fmax(0.000000, 0.000000) = 0.000000
fmax(-0.000000, -0.000000) = -0.000000
fmax(1.000000, -0.000000) = 1.000000
fmax(-1.000000, -0.000000) = -0.000000
fmax(-1.000000, 0.000000) = 0.000000
```

Comment: That's certainly the way I prefer: the convention of the first argument being returned if the arguments are equal. Nice explanation.

Comment: That works for the specific case I posted, but I'm also wanting to have -0.0 returned if they are both -0.0.

Comment: Well use the c standard library function signbit to distinguish. Valid from C99.

Comment: Simplify using @Bathsheba's suggestion and I'll mark this as correct.

Comment: Your solution would be portable if you used signbit. Would you mind reworking it? I've already upvoted.

Comment: @Bathsheba done, it's much much simpler with `signbit`, you're right. And thanks for the upvote. I try not to let supporters down :)

Answer (score 3):

From [fmax cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/fmax):

> This function is not required to be sensitive to the sign of zero,
>   although some implementations additionally enforce that if one
>   argument is +0 and the other is -0, then +0 is returned.

So I suppose it's up to you to specially handle the case that `-0.0` is returned.

Answer (score 2):

It's life I'm afraid. IEEE754 allows either -0.0 or +0.0 to be returned.

(Forgive me for assuming your implementation uses that scheme for floating point.)

More often than not, the first argument will be returned if the two values are equal. That could form the basis of a workaround, but it is not strictly portable.

You can use the C99 function signbit to distinguish a negative from a positive zero.

Answer (score 1):

> Why does fmax(a, b) return the smaller (negative) zero

`fmax()` compares *values*.  +0.0 and -0.0 have the same *value*.  Returning `a` or `b` meets the `fmax()` spec.  A spec footnote specifically addressing this:

> Ideally, `fmax` would be sensitive to the sign of zero, for example `fmax(−0. 0, +0. 0)` would return `+0`; however, implementation in software might be impractical. C11 #361

---

> how to cleanly workaround it?

Use `signbit()` to distinguish `+0.0` from `-0.0`.  [Other ways to distinguish +/-0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25332133/2410359)

> The `signbit` macro returns a nonzero value if and only if the sign of its argument value is negative C1dr §7.12.3.6 3

In addition to signed zeros, many floating point implementations allow *de-normal* or *not-a-numbers* (NaN).  In such cases, the usual preferred action is to return the "normal" number if any.

With `> < >= <=`, the result is false if at least one of the operands are NaN.
`a > b` is *not* the opposite of `a <= b`.  Both could be false.

Combing this with OP's zero compare goal of +0.0 beats -0.0:

```
#include <math.h>

float fmaxf_sz(float a,float b){
  if(!(a<b)) return b;  // a is known to be less than b, both are normal
  if(!(b<a)) return a;  // b is known to be less than a, both are normal


  if (a == b) {  // a is known to be equal in value to b, both are normal
    return signbit(a) ? b : a;
  }

  // One or both a,b are NaN
  return isfinite(a) ? a : b;
}
```

Or perhaps simply detect the special condition else use `fmaxf()` - similar to [@Jean-François Fabre](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43241106/2410359).  Note: use `fmaxf()` for maximum `float`.

```
float fmaxf_sz(float a,float b){
  if(a==0.0 && b==0.0) {
    return signbit(a) ? b : a;
  }
  return fmaxf(a,b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version of `fmaxf()` that looks at the `signbit()` in tie-breaking situations.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

float fmaxfs(float a,float b){
    if(a>b){
        return a;
    }
    if(b!=a){
        return b;
    }
    if(signbit(a)==0){
        return a;
    }
    return b;
}

int test(float a,float b,float e){
    float r=fmaxfs(a,b);
    printf("fmaxfs(%f, %f) = %f", a, b, r);
    if(r!=e||signbit(r)!=signbit(e)){
        printf(" ERROR\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}

int main () {
    int errors=0;
    errors+=test(0.0f,-0.0f,0.0f);
    errors+=test(-0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
    errors+=test(-0.0f,-0.0f,-0.0f);
    errors+=test(-0.7f,-0.8f,-0.7f);
    errors+=test(987.485f,100.0f,987.485f);
    errors+=test(987.485f,1000000.0f,1000000.0f);
    errors+=test(-987.485f,-100.0f,-100.0f);
    errors+=test(-1.3678f,-19999.6789f,-19999.6789f);

    if(errors>0){
        printf("%d ERRORS\n",errors);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

NB 1: Also note that if you are using `float` the best practice is to put `f` on the suffix or they will be interpreted as `double`.

I'll leave `fminfs` and a type generic macro as an exercise.

Comment: When `b` is [not-a-number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN), this code returns `b`.  `fmaxf(1.0, 0.0/0.0)` returns 1.0. Perhaps not an issue for OP.