# How can negative zero be tested for in PHP?

Tags: php, floating-point, php-7, zero, negative-number

In PHP there is a floating point negative zero, which compares identically to floating point positive zero `-0.0 === 0.0`, despite printing as different strings. There is no integer negative zero in PHP.

I'm writing an extended version of rounding functions and I'm trying to replicate PHP's native behaviour as much as possible. I'm writing it with TDD methodology, so I need a way to verify my code is in line with the native PHP functions by returning negative zero where PHP returns negative zero.

```php
<?php
var_dump(ceil(-0.5));
```

> ```
> double(-0)
> ```

Is there any way of testing for `-0.0` apart from:

- converting it to a string `(string)-0.0 === '-0'`
- serialising it `serialize(-0.0) === 'd:-0;'`

Comment: Why do you want to?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to have negative zero if zero is the absolute boundary of positive and negative.

Comment: What is the format of your source data?

Comment: Have you tried comparing to `0.0 * (-1)`?

Comment: I don't know PHP. In other languages you can use `(1.0/x) < 0.0`. The division turns the signed zero in `x` into +/-infinity, which can then be tested against zero.

Comment: @njuffa That's quite clever! PHP does differentiate between `INF` and `-INF`, however, the division by zero warning might kill my tests. I'll have to check.

Comment: @njuffa I was right. The warning raised when I divide by zero causes the unit test to fail. So close...

Comment: @njuffa I wish I could upvote you for inspiring the correct answer. I've upvoted your comment instead.

Comment: This C question may be useful [What operations and functions on +0.0 and -0.0 give different arithmetic results?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25332133/2410359)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@njuffa suggested `if (1 / $x === -INF)`, which works but throws a division by zero warning.

@Manu-sh modified it to do the same thing without the warning by using the new "power of" operator: `**`

```
<?php
function is_negative_zero($x) {
  return $x ** -1 === -INF;
}

echo is_negative_zero(0.0)? "Yes": "No";
echo PHP_EOL;

echo is_negative_zero(-0.0)? "Yes": "No";
echo PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

> ```
> No
> Yes
> ```

Answer (score 1):

This work *only for literals* but not for variables:

```
var_export(0.0 ** 0 == 1);
var_export(-0.0 ** 0 == -1);
```

But this seems to work also for variables:

```
// return 1 for positive zero, -1 for negative zero
// otherwise return 0
function zero_sign(float $x): int {

    if (($y = ($x ** -1)) === -INF)
        return -1;

    return $y === INF;
}

var_export(zero_sign(-0.0) === -1);
var_export(zero_sign(0.0)  ===  1);
var_export(zero_sign(-1.0) ===  0);
var_export(zero_sign(1.0)  ===  0);
```

You can check by yourself that this follow the mathematics rules,
here are the *Wolframalpha* results for [-0.0 ** -1](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-0.0%20**%20-1) and [0.0 ** -1](http://[wolfram%20result%20for:%200.0**-1][1])

Comment: the first output 1, the second -1

Comment: @CJDennis are you serius? this return a floating point number, check it by yourself with `var_dump(0.0 ** 0);` and `var_dump(-0.0 ** 0);`

Comment: and FYI there is no negative zero in two's complement representation

Comment: have you write "There is no integer negative zero in PHP.", yes it obvious

Comment: @CJDennis nevermind, i figured out that this work only on literal values..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200748/discussion-between-manu-sh-and-cj-dennis).

Comment: @CJDennis here is a way to do what you want to do

Comment: There's no need to keep discussing this as you've found a solution that works for me. Clean up your answer by removing the `echo` lines, add a short explanation of why/how it works, maybe how you came to the answer, and delete all your comments, then I'll delete all my comments too and mark this answer as accepted.

Comment: @CJDennis i have spent a bunch of time trying to find out a good solution for you, describing it and replying to your comments, be  and accept my answer.

Comment: If seems to only work for literals because of operator precedence: `-0.0 ** 0 === -(0.0 ** 0) === -1.0`. `(-0.0) ** 0 === 1.0` Change the code to the following and I'll accept it: `if ($x ** -1 === -INF)`.

Answer (score 0):

Floating point numbers have a specific bit that is set in the internal coding if it is negative. This test is also suitable to distinguish between +0.0 and -0.0. The test is also independent of how PHP performs operations with -0.0 and +0.0.

```
function isNegativFloat($value){
  return is_float($value) AND ord(pack('E',$value)) & 0x80;
}
```

Examples:

```
var_dump(isNegativFloat(0.0));  //bool(false)
var_dump(isNegativFloat(-0.0));  //bool(true)
var_dump(isNegativFloat(0.6));  //bool(false)
var_dump(isNegativFloat(-0.6));  //bool(true)
```

Special test for negative float zero:

```
function isNegativFloatNull($value){
  return $value === 0.0 AND isNegativFloat($value);
}
```

Examples:

```
var_dump(isNegativFloatNull(0.0));  //bool(false)
var_dump(isNegativFloatNull(-0.0));  //bool(true)
var_dump(isNegativFloatNull(0.6));  //bool(false)
var_dump(isNegativFloatNull(-0.6));  //bool(false)
```