# Is negative floating point zero guaranteed to evaluate to false in C?

Tags: c, floating-point, language-lawyer

I know that `0.0 == -0.0` and that the C standard says `if(a)` is equivalent to `if(a!=0)`, but:

Is `if(-0.0)` guaranteed to evaluate as `false` by the standard? Would an implementation be buggy if `if(-0.0)` is evaluated as true?

I guess the key point here is whether the `if(a!=0)` meaning of `if(-0.0)` must be understood as exactly the same `!=` operator as in floating point, in which case there would be guarantee that it must be false.

Comment: Sometimes using +0.0 and -0.0 have a [different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25332133/what-operations-and-functions-on-0-0-and-0-0-give-different-arithmetic-results) arithmetic result in code, but not with `if()`.

Comment: Note: `-0.0` is a double value, not a floating point value.  To make it a floating point value write it as: `-0.0f`  Notice the trailing 'f'

Comment: @user3629249 : Both `double` and `float` are floating point types, just like all the formats defined by IEEE 754.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C 2018 6.8.4.1 specifies the behavior of the `if` statement, with its `if … else` form. Paragraph 2 says:

> In both forms, the first substatement is executed if the expression compares unequal to 0…

Per the floating point model in C 2018 5.2.4.2.2 paragraphs 2 and 3 (which contain mathematical typography I will not reproduce here but say a floating-point number is defined by multiplying a sign +1 or −1 by a scaled power of the floating-point base and a sum of its digits each appropriately scaled for its position), the mathematical value of −0 is zero, the same as +0, so it compares equal to zero. Therefore `if (-0.)` will not execute the first substatement.