# C++ check input floats (-0.0f, +0.0f)

Tags: c++, floating-point, binary

I am currently trying to build a program which prints an input float value to binary.

The first bit is 0 if positive or 1  if negative,  but with an input value  of e.g.: -0.0g my if statement always prints 1, also for a positive input. How would I check that correctly?

```
string sign = "sign: ";
if(value <= -0.0f)
 sign.append("1\n");
else if (value >= 0.0f)
 sign.append("0\n");

...
```

Comment: Simple method, use the [signbit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/signbit) function.

Comment: [`std::signbit` on cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/signbit)

Comment: Note that, in IEEE 754, negative zero is a valid value.

Comment: @ChrisMM: More importantly, in IEEE754 positive and negative zero are _equal_. That's why the code fails `+0.0f <= -0.0f` is true, because `+0.0f == -0.0f`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

+0.0 and -0.0 have the same *value*, yet different *signs*.

`value <= -0.0f` is true for `value` as +0.0 and -0.0.  [@MSalters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74532771/c-check-input-floats-0-0f-0-0f/74534804#comment131569121_74532771)

To distinguish the sign, use `std::signbit()`. [@john](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74532771/c-check-input-floats-0-0f-0-0f/74534804#comment131567301_74532771)

```
if(std::signbit(value)) {
  sign.append("1\n");
} else {
  sign.append("0\n");
}
```

Note that `signbit()` also applies to infinities and NaN.

---

Even though [std::signbit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/signbit) reports "Along with `std::copysign`, `std::signbit` is one of the only two portable ways to examine the sign of a NaN.", there may be [others](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25332133/2410359).