# negative zero in identity

Tags: c++, floating-point, eigen3

I need to know if there is any detrimental impact on computations with this code

```
MatrixXd A = -Matrix<double,20,20>::Identity();
```

which creates the identity matrix with negative ones. Printing out the above matrix yields `-0` for the off-diagonal elements which from a mathematical point of view makes no sense. I'm asking this because the matrix needs to be passed to optimisation solver.

Comment: Well, I don't know if it doesn't make sense. For floating point arithmetic, zero is indistinguishable from a very small nonzero value. Negating that to achieve results like `1 / -0 == -infinity` makes sense to me. In any case, there are few ways (other than the one i just showed) to distinguish negative zero from positive zero, e.g. `+0. == -0.` is true. So what exactly do you worry could happen?

Comment: aritmetics with a signed zero is maths, just not the maths you are used to, but that is floating point maths anyhow. You can read about it here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero

Comment: @Homer512 "For floating point arithmetic, [zero is indistinguishable from a very small nonzero value](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17167312/homer512)." is unclear.  `DBL_MIN != 0`, `DBL_TRUE_MIN != 0`,  `-DBL_TRUE_MIN != 0`,  `1.0 != 0` are each true.  Zero and all non-zero value are distinguishable.

Comment: @CroCo You assert "above matrix yields -0 for the off-diagonal elements which from a mathematical point of view makes no sense.".   What about -0 does not make sense for you? Both -0.0 and + 0.0 have the same mathematical _value_.  If you want to avoid -0.0 as the result of some computation, simply add 0.0.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica What I mean is that floating point zero represents all real numbers in the range `(-DBL_TRUE_MIN; DBL_TRUE_MIN)`; or if you can be sure about the sign, then `[0; DBL_TRUE_MIN)`. In other words, floating point zero is indistinguishable from the nonzero real number `DBL_TRUE_MIN * 0.5`, for example.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica did you want to link somewhere? It points at my profile.

Comment: @Homer512 OK, so the [very small nonzero value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77842263/negative-zero-in-identity?noredirect=1#comment137231416_77842263) are not FP objects.

Comment: @Homer512.  Thank you, comment link fixed.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Ah, yes. IIRC the IEEE-754 standard would call these the *infinitely precise result* of a computation which is then *rounded to the nearest floating point value*. But that's semantics, I guess. It's clear we are on the same page here.

Comment: That is likely not what you are asking, but assigning a `Matrix<...>::Identity()` to a `MatrixXd` will always lose information which Eigen might otherwise use. E.g., `A += Matrix::Identity();` will (usually) be better than `MatrixXd I = Matrix<...>::Identity(); A+=I;`

Comment: Some floating point specifications (e.g. IEEE) support distinct positive and negative zero, which have different bitwise representations, but they are equal when comparing by value,  adding a positive zero to a value gives the same result as adding a negative zero, etc.   If infinities are supported, dividing `1.0` by a zero gives an infinity with the same sign as the zero.   Generally, performance implications of producing positive and negative zeros in floating point calculations are negligible (at worst) or non-existent - particularly if floating point operations are performed by hardware.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica "*What about -0 does not make sense for you?* " I do not see a definition for negative zero from pure abstract algebra. The real number algebraic structure distinguishes zero from positive and negative numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Floating point -0.0 and 0.0 have the same mathematical *value*.  The -0.0 in the matrix should pose no problem for an *optimisation solver*.  Consider -0.0 does come up in other subtle cases such as rounding of very small negative intermediate numbers toward 0.0 (e.g. `DBL_TRUE_MIN/-3.0`) and are not likely a special case for the optimizer.

[Some operations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25332133/2410359) use the sign of a zero to form distinctive results.  I could see your *optimisation solver* forming a -infinity when a +infinity would otherwise occur.

Adding 0.0 to a floating-point value, which might be -0.0, will normally drop the negative sign in the sum yet not affect the mathematical *value*.

---

I think of [-0.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero) as:

- Some math value that is negative, yet so small that it is closer to 0.0 than any encodable negative floating point value.
- The number is zero, yet its [genesis](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/genesis#Noun) is from the negative side.