# Can you safely check the sign of infinite?

Tags: c++, floating-point

In the past we have been using Visual Studio's _fpclass to understand if an infinite was positive or negative:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa246882%28v=vs.60%29.aspx

Passing to std::fpclassify, there's no distinction anymore between positive and negative infinite:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fpclassify

Can I safely check the sign of infinite with one of the methods here?
[Is there a standard sign function (signum, sgn) in C/C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1903954/2436175)

Note:

- Independently if [fastmath](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FloatingPointMath) is enabled
- In a portable way

Note 2:

- C++11 is applicable

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/signbit

Comment: @MarkDickinson Thanks! I think that should be an answer! Indeed the problem came out in the switch to C++11, so using signbit is an option

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For only checking the sign of an infinite value (as stated in the thread title), this code should suffice:

```
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::numeric_limits<T>::has_infinity, bool>::type Signed(T const& Value)
{
    return Value == -std::numeric_limits<T>::infinity();
}
```

Edit: If you have access to a C++11 ready compiler, there is also a function provided by the standard library, called `std::signbit` in the header `<cmath>`. It works for every fundamental floating point type and for every kind of value (so also for infinite and even for NaNs) and should therefore be a more general solution.

Comment: If you can mention also the signbit function linked by Mark Dickinson, this will be my accepted answer.

Comment: @Antonio Yeah, I can do that.

Answer (score 1):

You do not really need any special functions to detect infinities and NaNs:

```
double x = ...;
bool is_nan = x != x;
bool is_finite = !is_nan && x != 2 * x;
bool is_negative = !is_nan && x < 0;
```

Comment: +1. As numbers, `+inf` and `-inf` aren't particularly special. Most arithmetic on them won't produce `nan`s, and they compare like any other number.

Comment: The point is, `x != x` when fast math is enabled might return false!

Comment: @Antonio Do not enable options that screw up you maths then. Fast but wrong is not a virtue.

Comment: @Antonio If you expect NaNs, then you cannot use fast math.

Comment: This code is not portable, since `x != x` is no portable classification of NaN floats. The compiler isn't even forced to use the IEEE floating point standard.

Comment: @Conclusio You are incorrect. C standard requires that a NaN always compares unequal to any other value, even the identical NaN.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin I found nothing in the C++ working draft neither at [expr.eq] nor at [basic.fundamental]. Could you please tell me where to find it?

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin That's a “commentary” section in a book that is itself one person's commentary on the C and C++ standards. It is not written so rigorously that the sentence “A NaN always compares unequal to any other value, even the identical NaN” cannot be interpreted to have meant “A [IEEE-754] NaN always compares unequal to any other value, even the identical NaN”, since IEEE 754/IEC 60559 is the subject of the discussion in the previous sentences. Nothing here is binding for either C or C++ compilers, unless the compiler in question affirms its support for IEC 60559.

Comment: @PascalCuoq The author of that book knows what he talks about http://www.informit.com/authors/bio/86f640f5-f526-4915-b28b-62689c48f793

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin … which makes it even more conspicuous that the C standard does not say that `double` must have a `NaN` value or that such a value, if present, must compare different to itself. If Derek Jones wanted such a sentence to be present in the standard, he had the opportunity to try to try and slip it in there at the appropriate committee meetings. Therefore, it is a deliberate omission. The standard does not say that a NaN value must compare different to itself and that is on purpose.

Comment: The closest the C11 standard comes to saying that `NaN != NaN` is in clause 7.12.14 about comparison macros. But that section is really about the comparison macros, not `==`.

Comment: @PascalCuoq He states that the _terminology originates from IEC 60559 (or to be exact IEEE-754 and IEEE-854 standards that eventually became the ISO/IEC Standard)_. My guess is that C standard writers did not bother to copy another standard in its entirety and left it underspecified, not because they wanted NaN to compare equal to itself. And that explains his comment.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to already know that `x` is positive or negative infinity, you just don't know which. In that case, you'd use the same tactic you would if you knew `x` were `7` or `-7` but didn't know which:

```
x > 0
```

There's nothing wrong with that. Of course `x > 24` or comparison against any other finite value would work, since positive infinity is larger than all finite values and negative infinity is smaller than all finite values, but comparison with `0` seems like the most readable way to check for the sign.

If you're not sure whether `x` is infinity at all then test for it explicitly, as suggested in Fytch's answer:

```
if (x == std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity()) {
    // positive infinity
} else if (x == -std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity()) {
    // negative infinity
} else {
    // something else
}
```