# What is a CPU port and how does it influence performance?

Tags: performance, cpu

In low level performance oriented contexts, I've come across references to CPU ports. What is a CPU port and what makes them interesting from a software perspective?

After some trial and error it looks like "CPU execution port" is a much better Google phrase so I have some stuff to read but a 10,000 ft overview would still be helpful.

Two examples:

Intel's IACA reports information on ports:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26021338/1128289

This talk mentions ports:

https://youtu.be/Nsf2_Au6KxU

Comment: The word "port" can have at least three completely different meanings in the context of CPUs. If "execution port" is what you mean, please change the title; also please show us more context, e.g. a whole sentence where the word appears.

Comment: I titled it this way because if I was searching for this question I wouldn't know to search for *execution* port. "Port" without any qualifiers is how I've encountered it which makes it hard to google for.