# Using IACA with non-assembly routine

Tags: delphi, x86-64, micro-optimization, iaca

I've been playing around with [IACA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26021337/what-is-iaca-and-how-do-i-use-it) (Intel's static code analyser).
It works fine when testing with assembly snippets where I can input the magic marker bytes manually, like this:

```
procedure TSlice.BitSwap(a, b: integer);
asm
  //RCX = self
  //edx = a
  //r8d = b

  mov ebx, 111      // Start IACA marker bytes
  db $64, $67, $90  // Start IACA marker bytes

  xor eax, eax
  xor r10d, r10d

  mov r9d, [rcx]  // read the value
  mov ecx,edx     // need a in cl for the shift
  btr r9d, edx    // read and clear the a bit

  setc al         // convert cf to bit
  shl eax, cl     // shift bit to ecx position

  btr r9d, r8d    // read and clear the b bit

  mov ecx, r8d    // need b in ecx for shift
  setc r10b       // convert cf to bit
  shl r10d, cl    // shift bit to edx position

  or r9d, eax     // copy in old edx bit
  or r9d, r10d    // copy in old ecx bit

  mov [r8], r9d   // store result
  ret

  mov ebx, 222      // End IACA marker bytes
  db $64, $67, $90  // End IACA marker bytes
end;
```

Is there a way to prefix/suffix non assembly code with the required magic markers so that I can analyse the compiler generated code?

*I know I can copy-paste the generated assembly from the CPU view and create a routine using that, but I was hoping there is an easier workflow*

**EDIT**
I'm looking for solutions that work in the 64-bit compiler. I know I can mix assembly and normal code in the 32-bit compiler.

**UPDATE**
@Dsm's suggestion works. 
@Rudy's trick does not.

The following dummy code works:

```
Throughput Analysis Report
--------------------------
Block Throughput: 13.33 Cycles       Throughput Bottleneck: Dependency chains (possibly between iterations)

Port Binding In Cycles Per Iteration:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Port  |  0   -  DV  |  1   |  2   -  D   |  3   -  D   |  4   |  5   |  6   |  7   |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Cycles | 1.3    0.0  | 1.4  | 1.0    1.0  | 1.0    1.0  | 0.0  | 1.4  | 2.0  | 0.0  |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

N - port number or number of cycles resource conflict caused delay, DV - Divider pipe (on port 0)
D - Data fetch pipe (on ports 2 and 3), CP - on a critical path
F - Macro Fusion with the previous instruction occurred
* - instruction micro-ops not bound to a port
^ - Micro Fusion happened
# - ESP Tracking sync uop was issued
@ - SSE instruction followed an AVX256/AVX512 instruction, dozens of cycles penalty is expected
X - instruction not supported, was not accounted in Analysis

| Num Of |                    Ports pressure in cycles                     |    |
|  Uops  |  0  - DV  |  1  |  2  -  D  |  3  -  D  |  4  |  5  |  6  |  7  |    |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   3^   | 0.3       | 0.3 | 1.0   1.0 |           |     | 0.3 | 1.0 |     | CP | ret
|   X    |           |     |           |           |     |     |     |     |    | int3
[... more int3's]
|   X    |           |     |           |           |     |     |     |     |    | int3
|   1    | 1.0       |     |           |           |     |     |     |     |    | shl eax, 0x10
|   1    |           | 0.6 |           |           |     | 0.3 |     |     |    | cmp eax, 0x64
|   3^   |           | 0.3 |           | 1.0   1.0 |     | 0.6 | 1.0 |     | CP | ret
|   X    |           |     |           |           |     |     |     |     |    | int3
|   X    |           |     |           |           |     |     |     |     |    | int3
[...]
Total Num Of Uops: 8
```

**UPDATE 2**
If there is a call statement in there IACA seems to bomb and not want to analyse the code. Complaining about illegal instructions. However the basic idea works. Obviously you need to subtract the initial `ret` and its associated cost.

Comment: Both sequences are exactly 8 bytes. Can't you do: `X := $906764000000F6BB` at the start and `X := $906764000000DEBB` at the end of your routine, where `X` is an `UInt64`?

Comment: What good is static analysis if you can't change the machine code? <g>

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, to use as a base line for comparison. Non-assembly code can be inlined, assembly code cannot.

Comment: Did you try what I wrote and does it work? Could work at the beginning, but the one at the end might not.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, no that trick does not work. I label the int64 as volatile, so it does not get optimized away, and the moves + the actual bytes required do show up. However IACA disassembles the code and sees that the magic bytes are part of a 64-bit mov and ignores them: `COULD NOT FIND START_MARKER NUMBER 1`

Comment: Bummer. It is cleverer than I expected. <g>

Comment: How do you label an UInt64 as volatile in Delphi? Or are you using, say, C?

Comment: @RudyVelthuis `var [volatile] x:int64;`, see: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Compiler_Attributes

Comment: Hey, I learned something. Thanks. I must admit I had read about it, but forgotten again. <g>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't use IACA so I can't test this idea, and I will delete the answer if it does not work, but can you not just do something like this:

```
procedure TForm10.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  asm
    //RCX = self
    //edx = a
    //r8d = b

    mov ebx, 111      // Start IACA marker bytes
    db $64, $67, $90  // Start IACA marker bytes
  end;

  fRotate( fLine - Point(0,1), 23 );

  asm
    mov ebx, 222      // End IACA marker bytes
    db $64, $67, $90  // End IACA marker bytes

  end;
end;
```

This was just a sample routine from something else to check that it compiles, which it does.

Sadly this only works for 32 bit - as Johan points out it is not allowed for 64 bit.

For 64 bit the following may work, but again I cannot test it.

```
procedure TForm10.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  procedure Test1;
  asm
    //RCX = self
    //edx = a
    //r8d = b

    mov ebx, 111      // Start IACA marker bytes
    db $64, $67, $90  // Start IACA marker bytes
  end;
  procedure Test2;
  begin
    fRotate( fLine - Point(0,1), 23 );
  end;
  procedure Test3;
  asm
    mov ebx, 222      // End IACA marker bytes
    db $64, $67, $90  // End IACA marker bytes

  end;
begin
  Test1;
  Test2;
  Test3;
end;
```

Comment: The lastest version of IACA only works for x64 though. The 64-bit compiler does not allow mixing of assembly and normal code. It will work for 32 bit and older versions of IACA.

Comment: @Johan I modified the code for a sneaky version - I don't know if this is a bit too convoluted for your needs, though.

Comment: There will be a extraneous `ret` and perhaps some alignment code at the start of the routine, but it may very well work.