# How to count steps that an assembly program takes

Tags: assembly, slime

In general Assembly Language Program (such as SLIME), is there any quick way to count the steps that a particular program takes?

Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "steps", but **the relevant tool** for measuring is [Intel IACA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26021338/1305969).

Comment: If you have a debugger with any scripting features, write a debugger macro that increments a counter and single steps. 
 That will give you a dynamic instruction count.  Or if your CPU (or simulator) has performance counters, you can get the total instruction count that way.  (For modern computers, beware that it doesn't tell you very much about performance; instructions per clock can vary from 4 down to maybe 0.1 in real code on a Skylake CPU.  But for a super-simple CPU with a nearly-fixed instruction throughput, it could be a proxy for performance.)