# Why jnz counts no cycle?

Tags: performance, assembly, x86, micro-optimization, micro-architecture

I found in online resource that IvyBridge has 3 ALU. So I write a small program to test:

```
global _start
_start:
    mov rcx,    10000000
.for_loop:              ; do {
    inc rax
    inc rbx
    dec rcx
    jnz .for_loop       ; } while (--rcx)

    xor rdi,    rdi
    mov rax,    60      ; _exit(0)
    syscall
```

I compile and run it with `perf`:

```
$ nasm -felf64 cycle.asm && ld cycle.o && sudo perf stat ./a.out
```

The output shows:

```
10,491,664      cycles
```

which seems to make sense at the first glance, because there are 3 independent instructions (2 `inc` and 1 `dec`) that uses ALU in the loop, so they count 1 cycle together.

But what I don't understand is why the whole loop only has 1 cycle? `jnz` depends on the result of `dec rcx`, it should counts 1 cycle, so that the whole loop is 2 cycle. I would expect the output to be close to `20,000,000 cycles`.

I also tried to change the second `inc` from `inc rbx` to `inc rax`, which makes it dependent on the first `inc`. The result does becomes close to `20,000,000 cycles`, which shows that dependency will delay an instruction so that they can't run at the same time. So why `jnz` is special?

What I'm missing here?

Comment: Probably something related to [instruction fusing](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/macro-operation_fusion).

Comment: [CMP/TEST/ADD/SUB/INC/DEC/AND can fuse with Jcc](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/macro-operation_fusion) into a single macro operation

Comment: You might want to play with iaca (discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26021338/2189500)).  It lets you visualize some of this stuff.

Comment: note that [`xor edi, edi` would be better than `xor rdi, rdi`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33666617/995714) since it's shorter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, `dec/jnz` will macro-fuse into a single uop on Intel Sandybridge-family.  You could defeat that by putting a non-flag-setting instruction between the dec and jnz.

```
.for_loop:              ; do {
    inc rax
    dec rcx
    lea rbx, [rbx+1]    ; doesn't touch flags, defeats macro-fusion
    jnz .for_loop       ; } while (--rcx)
```

This will still run at 1 iter per cycle on Haswell and later and Ryzen because they have 4 integer execution ports to keep up with 4 uops per iteration.  (Your loop with macro-fusion is only 3 fused-domain uops on Intel CPUs, so SnB/IvB can run it at 1 per clock, too.)

See [Agner Fog's](https://agner.org/optimize/) optimization guide and especially his microarch guide.  Also other links in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info.

---

**Control dependencies are hidden by branch prediction + speculative execution, unlike data dependencies.**

Out-of-order execution and branch prediction + speculative execution hide the "latency" of the control dependency.  i.e. the next iteration can start running before the CPU verifies that `jnz` should really be taken.

So each `jnz` has an input dependency on the previous `dec rcx` before it can verify the prediction, but later instructions don't have to wait for it to be checked before they can execute.  In-order *retirement* makes sure that mis-speculation is caught before anything can "see" it happen (except for microarchitectural effects leading to the Spectre attack...)

---

10M iterations is not a lot.  I'd normally use at least 100M for something that runs at only 1c per iter.  Having a simple microbenchmark run for 0.1 to 1 second is normally good to get very high precision and hide startup overhead.

And BTW, you don't need `sudo perf` if you set `kernel.perf_event_paranoid = 0` with sysctl.  It's almost certainly better to do that than to use `sudo` all the time.

Comment: I've already convinced by the commenters that the cause is the macro-fusion. But your answer confuse me a lot, since you seem to say the `jnz` will be executed in the same cycle even without macro-fusion. I've tested by inserting `mov rsi, rdi` before `jnz` to prevent fusion, the result becomes 2cycle per iter. But if I insert `mov rsi, rdi` before `dec rcx`, the result is 1cycle per iter. So it seems the macro-fusion is the cause.

Comment: If branch prediction will execute `jnz` regardless of fusion, then how to explain this result?

Comment: I think I understand after reading some sections in Anger's book. When I insert `mov rsi, rdi` before `jnz`, the macro-fusion is prevented. So I end up with 3 uops for ALU, but `jnz` is also a uop for branch, which is at port 5 in IvyBridge and port 5 is an ALU as well. So these 4 uops can't be executed at the same time. Do I understand correctly? (though I still don't know why it becomes 2c/iter, perhaps I should ask a new question for that)

Comment: @user10865622 `jnz` will be executed in the same cycle even without macro-fusion *on Haswell and later and Ryzen* because there are more ports on these microarchitectures. The first three instructions together with `jnz` of the *previous* iteration can all be dispatched in the same cycle and complete execution in one cycle.

Comment: @user10865622: Adding another uop *and* preventing micro-fusion gives you 5 total fused-domain uops.  If you're on IvB, then you have a front-end bottleneck and it's a duplicate of [Is performance reduced when executing loops whose uop count is not a multiple of processor width?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53148682).  That means your loop can only issue at one iteration per 2 clocks, because SnB/IvB don't "unroll" loops inside the loop buffer: the taken loop branch has to be the last uop of an issue group (of up-to-4 uops).

Comment: @PeterCordes I haven't thought about front-end being bottleneck, now I can explain the cycle count both for my test and the `lea` example in your answer. Thanks a lot! A quick question: does the "taken branch" mean the branch instruction like `jnz`? I've encountered it many times, though I couldn't find the definition of "taken branch" from Google.

Comment: @user10865622: it means a branch that does jump, rather than falling through.  e.g. `jnz` if it runs when ZF is cleared.  Unconditional branches like `jmp` and `call` are always taken, but conditional branches (`jcc`) can fall through.  Fun fact: haswell and later have a branch execution unit on port 0 that can only handle predicted-not-taken branch and macro-fused-branch uops, as well as the regular branch execution unit on port 6 that can handle any branch.