# C++ get run time and memory usage

Tags: c++, performance, g++, performance-testing, benchmarking

I've been practicing my C++ programming on LeetCode and whenever I submit a solution it will tell me how long my program took to run and how much memory it used.

I'm using a mac and VSCode with g++ to compile my program locally. I want to find a tool or method I can use to get the same information about the run time and memory usage of my program so I can try tweaking it to see the effect on performance.

Is there a compiler option or something like a command line tool or VSCode extension I can run my program through or would I have to add code to my program to track the time and memory itself?

Comment: Back in the Day, `Xcode > Open Developer Tool > Instruments` was your best bet.  I don't have a Mac, so I don't follow Current Events very closely, but Q: Is XCode not an option these days?

Comment: @paulsm4 I'm sure XCode is powerful IDE for lots of things and especially if you're doing development specifically for apple hardware, however I usually prefer a lightweight editor like VSCode or Sublime Text and using the terminal for most of my work.

Comment: If you want "lightweight", use vi ;)  My preference is either a full-fledged IDE (Eclipse, MSVS or Android Studio come immediately to mind) or a text editor.  Otherwise, it's "notepad++" or "vi".  And "make" or "gradle" ;)  Anyway - the reason I brought up XCode is that it explicitly has the tools you need.  Or you can use gcc tools like [gprof](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/gprof/) (part of binutils, commonly installed alongside gcc).

Comment: @paulsm4 unfortunately it seems gprof doesn't work on macOS Mojave :(

Comment: Fair enough.  I still think trying XCode might be the fastest, easiest, most robust solution.  But Valgrind/callgrind is certainly worth a look, and to the extent it's CLI based, it should be pretty easy to integrate with VSCode: http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cl-manual.html.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For simple outputs, you can use [gnu time](https://dev.to/yuyabu/time-2-can-check-process-memory-usage-without-vmstat-or-sar-1no0).

As suggested on that page:

```
/usr/bin/time -f "time result\ncmd:%C\nreal %es\nuser %Us \nsys  %Ss \nmemory:%MKB \ncpu %P" <command>
```

For a version on Mac OSX, just take a look on this answer: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/235404

Answer (score 4):

You can use [valgrind](http://www.valgrind.org/) to find memory leaks or profiling. And [Google benchmark](https://github.com/google/benchmark) for code snippet benchmarks. Or you can measure time yourself with [chrono](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono).
And an online benchmark tool, [quick-bench](http://quick-bench.com/)

**Update:**

I found this nice info on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/86JgA6) which gives insights on the number of iterations or cycles...

Thanks to @[Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/224132/peter-cordes) the [tool](https://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/llvm-mca.html) 
llvm-mca estimates the Instructions Per Cycle (IPC), as well as hardware resource pressure.
Which is a simulation on a theoretical model of the CPU, not a profile but still could be useful. It also does not cover cache miss.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately valgrind and gprof aren't working on macOS Mojave (yet?), Google benchmark works but doesn't show the memory usage (as far as I can tell), quick-bench seems to only be for relative comparison benchmarking because it's running on AWS with unknown load. Looks like I will have to install xcode to use its Instruments profiler but it feels like overkill.

Comment: @DevinCrossman no problem. sees valgrind is out for Mojave https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=399584 they always have to wait till Apple releases the kernels. Hope that helps

Comment: LLVM-MCA is useful, but it's a simulation on a theoretical model of the CPU (I think assuming no cache misses, [like IACA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26021337/what-is-iaca-and-how-do-i-use-it)), *not* a profile.

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks I edited. You are right they stated that the cache hit or miss is not covered.