# efficient sign function in python for case of periodic boundary conditions

Tags: python, performance, numpy, cython

I have cython code I'm using to speed up a bottleneck in an otherwise pure python calculation. I have a pair of points in a periodic box of length Lbox (1d case is fine for this question). I need to compute the sign of y-x, and I need to flip this sign when the periodic boundary conditions are operative.

In the absence of PBCs, the following question provides the solution: [Is there a standard sign function (signum, sgn) in C/C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903954/is-there-a-standard-sign-function-signum-sgn-in-c-c). That solution is what I use to compute the *sgn* function.

```
def sgn(x, y):
    """ If x > y, returns 1. 
    If x < y, returns -1. 
    If x == y, returns 0. 
    """
    return (y < x) - (x < y)
```

The *sgn_pbc* function as written below returns the correct result, but is written inefficiently: the control flow within the *sgn_pbc* is the culprit for slowing down the PBC version. How can I write *sgn_pbc* in an analogous way to the *sgn* function, so that I avoid the clumsy control flow?

```
def sgn_pbc(x, y, Lbox):
    d = abs(x-y)
    if d <= Lbox/2.:
        return sgn(x, y)
    else:
        return -1*sgn(x, y)
```

Comment: In `sgn`, why aren't you using `np.sign(y-x)`?

Comment: For a pair of floats, the sgn function above is about 400% faster than np.sign

Comment: You tagged this with `numpy`.  Often the best way to speed things up is to vectorize the code, which is what numpy is all about.  Are you interested in vectorized solutions, where `x` and `y` are float *arrays*, or do you want to stick with "pairs of floats"?

Comment: Are these `python` or `cython` functions?  I see `def` but not `cdef`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First,

```
-1*sgn(x, y) == sgn(y, x)
```

then,

```
def sgn_pbc(x, y, Lbox):
    d = abs(x-y)
    if d <= Lbox/2.:
        return sgn(x, y)
    else:
        return sgn(y, x)
```

Also in Python, function calls are the most expensive operations. You can inline your `sgn`.

```
def sgn_pbc(x, y, Lbox):
    d = abs(x-y)
    if d <= Lbox/2.:
        return (y < x) - (x < y)
    else:
        return (x < y) - (y < x)
```

But then the `if` can be (mostly) rewritten as:

```
def sgn_pbc(x, y, Lbox):
    d = abs(x-y)
    w = sgn(Lbox/2., d)
    return  w * sgn(x, y)
```

And again, inlining the `sgn`,

```
def sgn_pbc(x, y, Lbox):
    d = abs(x-y)
    w = sgn(Lbox/2., d)
    return  w * (y < x) - (x < y)
```

I say mostly because the case where `d == Lbox/2.` this returns a wrong value.

Haven't timed it, though.

Comment: This was precisely the point where I got stuck: this approach would still require a control flow to correctly handle cases where d==Lbox/2, so there is no speedup at all.

Comment: Are those floating point values? Because you can add +eps to have a very low probability (1/2**53) of that equality being true.

Comment: Unless I misunderstand something, no matter what epsilon is added, the returned result will be incorrect when the distance exactly equals the Lbox/2+epsilon.

Comment: Yes. How probable is that?