# Traversing all the points inside a triangle using loops

Tags: c++, algorithm, loops

The following is the three vertices with x,y and z co-ordinates of a triangle in 3D:

```
-0.2035416, 0.1107585, 0.9516008 (vertex A)
-0.0334390, -0.2526040, 0.9751212 (vertex B)
0.2569092, 0.0913718, 0.9817184 (Vertex C)
```

The projection plane is divided into a grid of (height*width) pixels.

I want to traverse every pixel inside  the triangle inside the projection plane manually starting from the bottom to top of the triangle and **print each pixel co-ordinates**  inside the triangle on the screen in c++. Say, I have already found the top and bottom vertex of the triangle. But now, how will I traverse from bottom to top and print each pixel co-ordinate? What's the logic behind this?

I have an idea of making two nested for loops like below but what will I do inside the loops? how will I make the sideway move after each x and y increment?

```
for (int y = ymin; y <= ymax; ++y) {
   for (int x = xmin; x <= xmax; ++x) {

  //what to to here?

    }
 }
```

Comment: edited @jaggedSpire

Comment: Is the projection orthogonal? Is the y-axis the one pointing in or out from the screen?

Answer (score 1):

Traversing demo:

```
#include <iostream>

template <size_t kD>
class Vector{
public:
  template <class... Args>
  Vector(double coord, Args&&... args) {
    static_assert( sizeof...(args)+1 == kD, "Unmatched vector dimension" );
    InitCoord(0, coord, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }

  Vector(const Vector &) = default;
  Vector &operator=(const Vector &) = default;

  double &operator[](const size_t i) {
    return coord_[i];
  }
  double operator[](const size_t i) const {
    return coord_[i];
  }

  friend Vector<kD> operator-(const Vector<kD> &A, const Vector<kD> &B) {
    Vector v;
    for (size_t i=0; i<kD; ++i)
      v[i] = A[i]-B[i];
    return v;
  }
private:
  Vector() = default;

  template <class... Args>
  void InitCoord(const int pos, double coord, Args&&... args) {
    coord_[pos] = coord;
    InitCoord(pos+1, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }

  void InitCoord(const int pos) {}

  double coord_[kD];
};

class Line {
public:
  Line(const double x1, const double y1, const double x2, const double y2)
      : x1_(x1), y1_(y1), x2_(x2), y2_(y2) {}

  Line(const Vector<2> A, const Vector<2> B)
      : x1_(A[0]), y1_(A[1]), x2_(B[0]), y2_(B[1]) {}

  double operator()(const double x, const double y) const {
    return (y-y1_)*(x2_-x1_) - (x-x1_)*(y2_-y1_);
  }

  int_fast8_t Sign(const double x, const double y) const {
    return Signum( (y-y1_)*(x2_-x1_) - (x-x1_)*(y2_-y1_) );
  }
private:
  int_fast8_t Signum(const double x) const {
    return (0.0 < x) - (x < 0.0);
  }

  const double x1_,y1_;
  const double x2_,y2_;
};

void Transpos(Vector<2> &v) {
  v[0] = (v[0]+1)/2*720; // col
  v[1] = (v[1]+1)/2*480; // row
}

double CalculateZ(const Vector<2> &D, const Vector<2> &AB, const Vector<2> &AC,
    const Vector<3> &AB3, const Vector<3> &AC3) {
  const double b = (D[1]*AB[0]-D[0]*AB[1]) / (AC[1]*AB[0]-AC[0]*AB[1]);
  const double a = AB[0]==0 ? (D[1]-b*AC[1])/AB[1] : (D[0]-b*AC[0])/AB[0];

  std::cout << a << " " << b << std::endl;

  return a*AB3[2]+b*AC3[2];
}

int main()
{
  const auto A3 = Vector<3>(0.0, 0.0, 7.0);
  const auto B3 = Vector<3>(0.0, 0.3, 9.0);
  const auto C3 = Vector<3>(0.4, 0.0, 1.0);

  const auto AB3 = B3-A3;
  const auto AC3 = C3-A3;
  const auto BC3 = C3-B3;

  // Some projection works here, which I am not good at.
  // A B C store the projected triangle coordiate in the [-1,1][-1,1] area

  auto A = Vector<2>(0.0, 0.0);
  auto B = Vector<2>(0.0, 0.3);
  auto C = Vector<2>(0.4, 0.0);

  Transpos(A);
  Transpos(B);
  Transpos(C);

  const auto AB2 = B-A;
  const auto AC2 = C-A;
  const auto BC2 = C-B;

  const Line AB(A, B);
  const Line AC(A, C);
  const Line BC(B, C);

  const auto signAB = AB.Sign(C[0],C[1]);
  const auto signAC = AC.Sign(B[0],B[1]);
  const auto signBC = BC.Sign(A[0],A[1]);

  // top
  // 0------------720 (col x)
  // |
  // |
  // |
  // |
  // 480 (row y)
  // bottom

  for (int row=480-1; row>=0; --row) {
    for (int col=0; col<720; ++col) {
      if (signAB*AB.Sign(col,row)>=0 && signAC*AC.Sign(col,row)>=0 &&
          signBC*BC.Sign(col,row)>=0 )
        std::cout << row << "," << col << " Z:"
          << CalculateZ(Vector<2>(col, row)-A, AB2, AC2, AB3, AC3) + A3[2]
          << std::endl;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Projection:

- first space [-1,1][-1,1]
- second space [0,720][0,480]

Let's say we have a (x1,y1) in the first space, then (x_,y_) with x_=(x1+1)/2*720, y_=(y1+1)/2*480 will be in the second space.

More generalize:

```
first space [xmin,xmax][ymin,ymax]
second space [xmin_,xmax_][ymin_,ymax_]
(x1,y1)
->
( (x1-xmin)/(xmax-xmin)*(xmax_-xmin_)+xmin_ ,  
  (y1-ymin)/(ymax-ymin)*(ymax_-ymin_)+ymin_ )
```

If you just want to zoom it, not twist it or something...

**Edit #1:**

- Thanks to @Adrian Colomitchi's advices, which is outstanding, I have
  improved the demo.
- `Ax Ay Bx By Cx Cy` are now coordinates in the first space, they are
  then "transposed" into the second space. As a result, `Line AB AC BC`
  are now "in" the second space. And the two loops are modified
  accordingly, they now iterate the points of the second space.

**How to find z value from (x,y):**

AB represents a vector from A(Ax,Ay) to B(Bx,By), i.e. AB = B-A = (Bx-Ax,By-Ay).

For any given point D(Dx,Dy) in the triangle, represent it into AD = a*AB + b*AC : (Dx-Ax, Dy-Ay) = a*(Bx-Ax, By-Ay) + b*(Cx-Ax, Cy-Ay) where Dx Dy Ax Ay Bx By Cx Cy is known. Find out a and b, and then Dz = a*(Bz-Az) + b*(Cz-Az). Dx Dy in the 3D space can be calculated the same way.

**Edit #2:**

Z value calculation added to the demo.

I tried to keep the demo simple, but calculating the Z value really involved lots of variables and calculations. I declare a new class called Vector to manage points and vectors, while the Line class remains unchanged.

Comment: You have shown here for vertex co-ordinates but I want to convert them into pixel-co ordinates as I have mentioned the projection plane is divide into a grid of (720*480) pixels. i want to output all the pixel values inside which all the points of the triangle belong to, not the original vertex values. can you tell me how I will do that? @felix

Comment: The "sign" operator (the `double operator()(double,double y)` one) - you can replace it with the equivalent of `return (y-y1_)*(x2_-x1_) - (x-x1_)*(y2_-y1_);` Saves two comparison, which you can use back to transform your returned type to one of the [`int_fastX_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) via a specially crafted ['signum`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4609795/620908) function. As you have O(N^2) complexity in your cycle, switching from FP multiplication to int multiplication may squeeze some extra performance.

Comment: According to the rule you have showed, if the point (0.256,0.0914) is in first space, then it will be in ((0.256+1)/(2*720),(0.0914+1)/2*480) in the second space. But it  will be fractional values. Can pixel values be fractional? Will I need to take floor or ceiling of it? @felix

Comment: if I put, const double Ax = -0.2035416,Ay = 0.1107585; const double Bx = -0.0334390,By = -0.2526040; const double Cx = 0.2569092,Cy = 0.0913718; in the code of felix, I am getting (0,0) as output, Does this mean, only the point (0,0) belongs to the triangle? @felix

Comment: Yes, it will be a fractional value. Next step is figuring out that the point locate in which pixel. One simple way is rounding the coordinates, i.e. (x,y) locates at pixel (floor(x),floor(y)), and the original space must be changed to [-1,1)[-1,1). Yes point (0,0) belongs to the triangle. You can change the range of for, and step of it, and the type of the iterator, to get a more precise output.

Comment: Thanks for your edited code. But, what if a vertex (say vertex A) lies outside the projection plane [-1,1] and the others (say, vertex B and C) inside? I need to discard the outside part and print only those pixels that are inside the projection plane. Of course then, the shape may not be a triangle rather any polygon.  Does your code do that? @felix

Comment: The current demo can correctly deal with it. In fact, no actual space are defined, the code always work in the range a double can represent. In a word, this demo will only output the point which is inside **both** the triangle area and the second area.

Comment: Thanks again for your explanation. Another question not directly related to this: is there any way to calculate the z  value at each pixel inside those two for  loops? is there any mathematical formula for this? @felix

Comment: You are welcome, I have edited my answer and added a part which explain how to find z value.

Comment: If I declare a 2D array as double zbuffer[screen_width][screen_height], is it possible to store the z values of all the pixels traversed  inside the nested for loops in the 2D array using the row and col values? I am very new to this topic. Can you please edit the code to add this z value calculation? @felix

Comment: inside the second for loop, if I write zbuffer[row][col]=z, will it be correct? or should I write zbuffer[col]rowl]=z? @felix

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the inner loop slightly; don't go from xmin to xmax. For each value of y from ymin to ymax there will be exactly two different pixels (two different x values) which lie exactly on the two edges of the triangle. Calculate those points and then all points between them will be inside the triangle. And you'll have to handle some edge cases such as when one of the edges is horizontal.

Comment: "For each value of y, there will be exactly two different x values"- can you please explain this a little bit? and what is the formula of calculating those two values? Moreover, after calculating these two x values, how will I get all the points between them? Is there any mathematical formula fr this ? @ccarton

Answer (score 0):

First you must transform your {0,1} ranges (vert & horz) to pixel coordinates. You speak of 720x480. This is not a square, but a rectangle. If you decide to keep one-to-one scale, you'll get a distorted triangle. If not, perhaps you only use 480x480 pixels.

Second, now you have your three vertices in pixel-space, you can iterate every pixel in this pixel-space and tell if it belongs to the triangle or not. The function 'InTriangle' for this job is what  @felix posted in the code of his solution:

```
if (signAB*AB(i,j)>=0 && signAC*AC(i,j)>=0  && signBC*BC(i,j)>=0 )
```