# How do you transform a number to its sign?

Tags: c++

How do you transform a number to its sign (for example -50 = -1, 50 = 1) without using the if statement, just mathematical operations?

Comment: no sign bit to look?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a standard sign function (signum, sgn) in C/C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903954/is-there-a-standard-sign-function-signum-sgn-in-c-c)

Comment: Untested, but have you tried `1 | (n & (1 << (sizeof(n) * 8) - 1))`? I'll leave it up to you to figure out what all of that does.

Comment: Why so many downvotes? Too easy to answer?

Comment: It's usually simplest just to test it: `(x < 0) ? -1 : (x > 0) ? +1 : 0;`.  Improving on that is hard — unless you can get at the flags from an assembler comparison so you only do one comparison, not two.  If the value is non-zero, `x / abs(x)` gives you the right answer, but it costs a division plus the absolute-value operation.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik I'd like to know your answer using the sign bit

Comment: @gigi compare your number to positive zero implementation defined

Comment: I just found the perfect answer : (x > 0) - (x < 0) it uses a condition but not an "if" so I guess it's ok

Comment: @gigi My guess is because it's a trivial mathematical problem so dear to universities yet unrelated to C++. It brings very little to the (C++) table.

Comment: @gigi `(x > 0) - (x < 0)` has no branching conditions - the `>` and `<` are operators which return a numerical value.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just do this

```
int sign = i<=0 ? -1 : 1;
```

Comment: Why not?  It has a branch... see (from the dupe) : http://stackoverflow.com/a/1903975/327083

Comment: Nothing in *this* question mentioned a branch, just that it shouldn't use an `if` statement :-) This answer is wrong for a totally *different* reason: zero is *not* negative.

Comment: Thank you - my answer does not have an if in it. In fact it does not have a f but has an i - sorry for the use of a vowel