# How is the three-way comparison operator different from subtraction?

Tags: c++, comparison-operators, c++20, spaceship-operator

There's a new comparison operator `<=>` in C++20. However I think in most cases a simple subtraction works well:

```
int my_strcmp(const char *a, const char *b) {
    while (*a == *b && *a != 0 && *b != 0) {
        a++, b++;
    }
    // Version 1
    return *a - *b;
    // Version 2
    return *a <=> *b;
    // Version 3
    return ((*a > *b) - (*a < *b));
}
```

They have the same effect. I can't really understand the difference.

Comment: Integer subtraction is an old hack to perform 3-way comparison, but it may suffer from overflow. It doesn't work *always* for unsigned types either. An alternative way is ((*a > *b) - (*a < *b))

Comment: There was even talk of allowing any type with a defaulted `<=>` to be a non-type template parameter. This operator has consequences beyond being a replacement for one operation that "works" only on arithmetic types.

Comment: @iBug: So... what exactly do you plan to do for doing 3-way comparisons on things that *aren't* arrays of characters?

Comment: As you said, in most cases a simple subtraction works well. What about all the other cases?

Comment: @edc65 That's what I'm asking

Comment: You are lucky in the sense that the domains you work with are small. You could just write a test that exhaustively verifies whether your function works the way you expect it to (there are only `(2 ** sizeof(char)) * (2 ** sizeof(char))` comparisons you need to do.)

Comment: @wvxvw Did you mean `(2 ** (sizeof(char) * CHAR_BIT))`?

Comment: @iBug yes, that.

Comment: It may seem beside the point, but: If `*a == *b && *a != 0` then we already know that `*b != 0`, so we shouldn't include that check in the loop.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The operator solves the problem with numeric overflow that you get with subtraction: if you subtract a large positive number from a negative that is close to `INT_MIN`, you get a number that cannot be represented as an `int`, thus causing undefined behavior.

Although version 3 is free from this problem, it utterly lacks readability: it would take some time to understand by someone who has never seen this trick before. `<=>` operator fixes the readability problem, too.

This is only one problem addressed by the new operator. Section 2.2.3 of [Herb Sutter's *Consistent comparison* paper](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2017/p0515r0.pdf) talks about the use of `<=>` with other data types of the language where subtraction may produce inconsistent results.

Comment: can you please explain the trick to understanding the 3rd version? It looks like (false/true - true/false) to me

Comment: @asgs This trick exploits "duality" of Booleans in C/C++, where `true` and `false` values returned by comparison operators are actually integers `1` and `0`, respectively. [This Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4609795/335858) provides more details about this trick.

Answer (score 43):

Here are some cases that subtraction won't work for:

1. `unsigned` types.
2. Operands that cause integer overflow.
3. User-defined types that don't define `operator -` (perhaps because it's not meaningful - one may define an order without defining a notion of distance).

I suspect this list is non-exhaustive.

Of course, one can come up with workarounds for at least #1 and #2.  But the intent of `operator <=>` is to encapsulate that ugliness.

Comment: Note that doing 3-way comparisons on strings (not mere `const char*` but an actual string class) is a reasonable operation. Subtracting two strings is not.

Answer (score 18):

There are some meaningful answers here on the difference, but Herb Sutter in [his paper](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2017/p0515r0.pdf) specifically says:

> <=> is for type implementers: User code (including generic code) outside the implementation of an operator<=> should almost never invoke an <=> directly (as already discovered as a good practice in other languages);

So even if there was no difference, the point of the operator is different: to aid class writers to generate comparison operators.

The core difference between the subtraction operator and the "spaceship" operator (according to Sutter's proposal) is that overloading `operator-` gives you a subtraction operator, whereas overloading `operator<=>`:

- gives you the 6 core comparison operators (even if you declare the operator as `default`: no code to write!);
- declares whether your class is comparable, is sortable, and whether the order is total or partial (strong/weak in Sutter's proposal);
- allows for heterogeneous comparisons: you can overload it to compare your class to any other type.

Other differences are in the return value: `operator<=>` would return an `enum` of a class, the class specifies whether the type is sortable and whether the sort is strong or weak. The return value would convert to -1, 0 or 1 (though Sutter leaves room for the return type to also indicate distance, as `strcmp` does). In any case, assuming the -1, 0, 1 return value, we'll finally get [a true signum function in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903954/is-there-a-standard-sign-function-signum-sgn-in-c-c)! (`signum(x) == x<=>0`)