# Explanation for template signum

Tags: c++, templates

I came across this template of C++

```
template <typename T> int sgn(T val) {
        return (T(0) < val) - (val < T(0));
    }
```

And I have to admit I don't really get it.
If I try to do a numeric application, let's say -1: 
(0<(-1))-(-1 < 0) => False - True I get a subtraction of Bool.
Is that how it should work? Can someone explain the different steps the compiler will do?

Comment: You get an implicit conversion there. False => 0, True=>1. So you get `return 0 - 1`

Answer (score 1):

There are implicit conversions happening there: `True=>1` and `False=>0`.

You need to check both conditions to see if the value could be equal to zero - that's how signum is defined. If your interested in checking only greater or lower than 0, you could get away with a single comparison.

Nevertheless, having your example with `-1` and the posted template, in result you get:

`return False - True;` => `return 0 - 1;` => `return -1;`

Answer (score 1):

It will return-1 if negative +1 if possitive 0 if 0
lets say -1:

```
(T(0) < val) - (val < T(0))
0<-1 false or 0
-
-1 < 0 true or 1
0 - 1  = -1
```

lets say 0

```
(T(0) < val) - (val < T(0))
0<0 false or 0
-
0 < 0 false or 0
0 - 0  = 0
```

lets say 1:

```
(T(0) < val) - (val < T(0))
0<1 true or 1
-
1 < 0 false or 0
1 - 0  = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

false and true would be converted to 0 and 1. So depending if one or both expressions evaluate to false, you get -1, 0, 1  results. That's a canon definition of signum function.

PS.Thats not an effective template, for better work there should be three specializations.

This question features answer that explains those:
[Is there a standard sign function (signum, sgn) in C/C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903954/is-there-a-standard-sign-function-signum-sgn-in-c-c)