# How can I simplify my long if else statement

Tags: c++

I hope someone could help me to simplify this expression. As shown below there are 2 values that will be checked. Acoording to both of these values, I have to update an image.
I tried some stuff but everything leads back to this long if else statement
I am not sure whether this has been asked before since I am not sure what to search for. If you could provide me some known previous question would be helpful too.
I have value x and y which represent the position of a gps receiver from the center of a car. And depending on this position, I have to update the position of the gps in the image shown to the user.

```
    if (val > 0)
    {
       if (secondVal > 0)
       {
          SetIcon("right_front.png")
       }
       else if (secondVal< 0)
       {
          SetIcon("right_back.png")
       }
       else
       {
          SetIcon("right_center.png")
       }
    }
    else if (val < 0)
    {
       if (secondVal > 0)
       {
          SetIcon("left_front.png")
       }
       else if (secondVal < 0)
       {
          SetIcon("left_back.png")
       }
       else
       {
          SetIcon("left_center.png")
       }
    }
    else
    {
       if (secondVal > 0)
       {
          SetIcon("center_front.png")
       }
       else if (secondVal < 0)
       {
          SetIcon("center_back.png")
       }
       else
       {
          SetIcon("center_center.png")
       }
    }
```

Comment: your example is equivalent to : `;` (unless `>` has sideeffects). What do you want to simplify?

Comment: It is not possible to meaningfully suggest alternative approaches without knowing more about what the overall code is trying to do. It's entirely possible that whichever logic ended up producing the mysteriously-named `val` and `secondVal` is suboptimal, and the correct approach will come nowhere close this rabbit hole. Or, perhaps a 2d lookup table will be sufficient. Can't really say without knowing what this is attempting to accomplish.

Comment: Please provide more context. This seems like an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Ultimately, if you have these possible conditions and the outcome for each is different, then that's what you have. The only improvements we could make would be in the surrounding machinery (like Sam said). You should provide more context, ideally a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks for the reply everyone. Sorry for the incomplete question. I have value x and y which represent the position of a gps receiver on a car for example. And depending on this position, I have to update the position of the gps in the image shown to the user. I will update the code

Comment: I'm also in favor of the lookup table but as your icon naming seems to be consistent, you can also build the name of the file by sequentially checking `val` (would give you `left_`, `center_` or `right_`) and `secondVal`(would give you `front.png`, `back.png` or `center.png`). Then you concat both and you have it.

Comment: Something I've been curious about for a long time, now I've created a small library which could probably help solve this problem: https://gitlab.com/bipll/quadrant.cpp So, for instance, in your case it would be `switch(nstd::quadrant(val, secondVal)) { case nstd::quadrant(-1, -1): SetIcon("left_back.png"); break; /* ... */ }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
std::string direction = val ? val < 0 ? "left" : "right" : "center";
std::string orientation = secondVal ? secondVal < 0 ? "back" : "front" : "center";

setIcon(direction + "_" + orientation + ".png");
```

Answer (score 2):

Wel, let's face it: you need to cover the following cases:

```
val Secondval
  0         0
  0        >0
  0        <0
 >0         0
 >0        >0
 >0        <0
 <0         0
 <0        >0
 <0        <0
```

Those are nine cases, and your if-else loop contains nine cases, so I don't think it's possible to simplify this.

Obviously, if there are some doubles in the actions that need to be taken, the whole story can change:

```
val Secondval  action to take
  0         0        action_1
  0        >0        action_1
  0        <0        action_1
 >0         0        action_2
 >0        >0        action_2
 >0        <0        action_2
 <0         0        action_2
 <0        >0        action_2
 <0        <0        action_2
```

Here, you might simplify to:

```
if (val == 0) {
  action_1;
} else {
  action_2;
}
```

So, if you do have repeating actions, it might be interesting to make a table like the one I showed and see what you can do.

Comment: Sorry for not being so detailed earlier. I just updated my code. I believe in my case the actions are all different

Comment: Upvoted because, even if it's not what OP wanted in the updated question, it's anyway the right approach and there's nothing more to say

Comment: @IwanRaflis: allthough you have different actions for every case, they are related one to the other. I was about to explain this by editing my answer, but then I've seen that my colleagues have already given that answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this for your specific case

```
    std::string icon;

    if (val > 0){
        icon = "right";
    }
    else if (val < 0){
        icon = "left";
    }
    else{
        icon = "center";
    }

    if (secondVal > 0)
    {
        icon += "_front.png";
    }
    else if (secondVal< 0)
    {
        icon += "_back.png";
    }
    else
    {
        icon += "_center.png";
    }

    SetIcon(icon);
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, this code can be simplified, because all your 9 actions are more or less the same.  Base your solution on the signum function (which returns -1 for numbers less than 0, 0 for 0, and 1 for numbers greater than 0). Here is a `signum` implementation from another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903954/is-there-a-standard-sign-function-signum-sgn-in-c-c):

```
template <typename T> int sgn(T val) {
    return (T(0) < val) - (val < T(0));
}
```

Now the idea is to convert your numbers `val` and `secondVal` to an integer from 0 to 8 and then use that as index into an array.

```
int idx = (sgn(val)+1)*3+(sgn(secondVal)+1);
SetIcon(icons[idx]);
```

The first part converts `val` into integers 0, 3, and 6 based on whether it is negative or not.  Then we add the `secondVal` as 0, 1, and 2, again, based on whether it is negative or not.  You just have to create an array with the correct ordering of the values.

```
char *icons[] = { "left_back.png", "left_center.png", "left_front.png",
                  ... };
```

Answer (score 0):

Having three versions of essentially the same code suggests that you need to write a function:

```
void select_icon(int value, const char* gt_value, const char* lt_value, const char* eq_value) {
    if (value > 0)
        SetIcon(gt_value);
    else if (value < 0)
        SetIcon(lt_value);
    else
        SetIcon(eq_value);
}
```

and then just call it:

```
if (val > 0)
    select_icon(secondValue, "right_front.png", "right_back.png", "right_center.png");
else if (val < 0)
    select_icon(secondValue, "left_front.png", "left_back.png", "left_center.png");
else
    select_icon(secondValue, "center_front.png", "center_back.png", "center_center.png");
```

This particular problem has more commonalities that can be exploited, as other answers have suggested: build the name on the fly, or use a two-dimensional array indexed by `signum`. I mention refactoring because that should probably be your first instinct when you see redundant code. My inclination is to write a function whenever I have more than one level of logic nesting. Sometimes it's easier to keep the code all in a single function, but most of the time refactoring makes things much smaller and clearer.