# Fast add/subtract two integers based on sign of third integer

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

I am looking for a fast (branch-less) code to compute the following:

```
if ( k > 0 )
    x += i;
else if ( k < 0 )
    x -= i;
else if ( k == 0 ) 
    // do nothing.
```

where `k`, `x`, and `i` are of `int` type.

It is fine for the solution to use intrinsics.

Comment: You've busted the compiler generating inefficient code for this?

Comment: How do you know it's not branchless?

Comment: user2052436,  Approaches using `x += signof(k)*i;` suffer from potential UB when `i == INT_MIN, k < 0`. Do you care about this corner case?

Comment: The question and all the currently posted answers are all wild speculation. Discussing this without showing the generated machine code for some CPU is quite pointless.

Comment: @Lundin the nature of a micro-optimization question like this is that there's no single best answer.  The only thing you can do is collect a number of different approaches and benchmark them in your own final configuration.  There's already an assumption built into the question that branchless will be faster, but that's not a given either.

Answer (score 4):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4609795/8372853) shows a fast, branchless way of computing the sign of a value. Assuming that's correct, you can write:

```
x += i * ((0 < k) - (k < 0))
```

Comment: This very much depends on the compiler having a branchless way to evaluate `0 < k` and `k < 0`.

Comment: @MarkRansom Couldn't say for sure. The linked answer claims it's branchless, and I'm just building upon that. Is the phrasing better now?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```c
int sign = !!k - !!(k & INT_MIN) * 2;
x += i * sign;
```

This assumes two's complement representation of integers, resulting in `INT_MIN` having only the high-order bit set.

Comment: @MarkRansom Added assumptions.

Comment: Worth noting that since C++20 this assumption is guaranteed.

Comment: @eerorika did C++20 mandate two's complement integer representation?  That's quite a leap.  In the past they've always tried to be accommodating to weird architectures.

Comment: @MarkRansom They did. I don't know if there are C++20 implementations for other archs but they will have to emulate two's complement if they want to conform.

Comment: Why not replace `INT_MIN` with `~INT_MAX` and forget about whether or not it's two's complement?

Answer (score 1):

Just compile your code with good optimisation settings, get a disassembly of your code, and look at the result. Then change your code until the disassembly shows what you want. There's a chance that you already get branchless code. There's a better chance if you write

```
if ( k > 0 )
    x += i;
if ( k < 0 )
    x -= i;
```

because the else in between makes it harder for the compiler to avoid branches.

Answer (score 1):

```
x = x + i*(k>0) - i*(k<0);
```

But, honestly, given the many optimization possibilities of modern compilers, I wouldn't trade clarity of code for aleggedly faster code. For the x86 platform, for example, MMX and SSE units can do this operation with no branches.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be expecting code that is "branchless" to be measurably and importantly "faster?"  With maximum optimization settings turned on, exactly what instruction sequence does your compiler now produce?  Have you then *profiled* that code to confirm that it is not fast enough?

Comment: While it's a fair question, I feel like this is more of a comment than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at the assembly language for this:

```cpp
if (k != 0)
{
    const int multiplier = (k > 0) ? 1 : -1;
    x += (multiplier) * i;
}
```

Some processors may have conditional instructions that are only executed depending on the condition code (like ARM).

Look at the assembly code printed by your compiler.

**Edit 1: performance concerns**
A lot of modern processors have enough space in their instruction cache to that they can handle the above code efficiently.  The comparison should be quick for the processor's branch decision making circuitry.

**Profile** or **Benchmark** before making any judgements about code having to be one line.

Answer (score 0):

Just for kicks, I present this:

```cpp
using opType = void(*)(int&, int);
const opType ops[3] =
{
    [](int&  , int  ){ },
    [](int& x, int i){ x += i; },
    [](int& x, int i){ x -= i; }
};

auto f = ops[int(k > 0) + (2 * int(k < 0))];
f(x, i);
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/SIL7eB)

Obviously, the other solutions using solely mathematics are going to be more efficient :)  But this give you some options if you want to do more complex operations based on what `k` is.

Comment: Now I'm itching to see the assembly for this :)

Comment: Oh, I wasn't actually asking for the link, but thanks :) Hmm, even at O3 there appear to be jumps that don't get optimized out. Not that I'm any good at reading assembly.

Answer (score 0):

Except for INT_MIN the following should work in C++11

```
x += (std::signbit(-k)-std::signbit(k))*i;
```

And the following should work in all cases, including INT_MIN - if long is longer than int:

```
x += (std::signbit(-(long)k)-std::signbit(k))*i;
```

**Added**: Internally std::signbit is in many compilers converted to a simple shift-operation, which should be branch-less and fast.

Answer (score -2):

This is a branchless solution, but the time will vary based on your environment.  It shouldn't take too much more than 0.005 seconds, so I think that won't be a problem.

```c
k>0?x+=i:k<0?x-=i:0
```

Comment: Ternary operators are like branches or `if` statements.