# Understanding template function declarations

Tags: c++, templates

First place I saw syntax I didn't understand was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903954/is-there-a-standard-sign-function-signum-sgn-in-c-c/10133700).

```
template <typename T> int sgn(T val) {
    return (T(0) < val) - (val < T(0));
}
```

Had a couple other small questions as I read [this](https://www.cplusplus.com/doc/oldtutorial/templates/).

```
template <class T>
class mypair {
    T a, b;
  public:
    mypair (T first, T second)
      {a=first; b=second;}
    T getmax ();
};

template <class T>
T mypair<T>::getmax ()
{
  T retval;
  retval = a>b? a : b;
  return retval;
}
```

What I (think) I understand:

1. Templates are used to help keep the DRY principle.
2. Templates have the common attributes across classes that you want to be able to use.

#### Let's start with the *first* code example.

To me, it looks like there are two return types but I think I'm supposed to read it as "this is a `template` function with `<typename T>` where `T` is the class. Therefore, only for this function, declare `T` as a class which will be determined at compile time and will by the class called `T`. This function will return an `int`.

Is that a correct understanding of the function declaration? It seems strange to have to declare `template <class T>` but it looks like when you have more than one template class you list them like so `template <class T, class U>`.

Where in the code do we actually declare what attributes `T` has and fit under that template? Is that what `mypair` is being declared as in the next block? If I wanted `mypair` to also be considered a `U` would I just say `template <class T, class U> class mypair {...`

#### Second code example.

The specificate part I'm trying to understand is the declaration for getmax `template <class T> T mypair<T>::getmax ()`

I think `mypair<T>::getmax()` is saying that we're declaring the `getmax` function for `mypair`. What does the `T` in `mypair<T>` refer to?

#### Final clarification question.

From what I read, it sounds like the main complaint about using templates is that they can increase compile time but it sounds like they have no impact on run time. Right?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "a template function" or "a template class". They are "a function template" and "a class template". They are *recipes* to automatically generate functions and classes as needed.

Comment: So what's the difference between writing a recipe and following the recipe? Seems like if you have to write it out, then you've written it out

Comment: You write the recipe, the compiler follows it. From a single function template, as many functions as can fit in memory can be created *automatically*. Consider what hapens when you use `std::vector<my_type>`. This creates an entire resizable, safe, dynamic array type specifically dedicated to handling vectors of that specific type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with:

```
template <typename T> int sgn(T val) {
    return (T(0) < val) - (val < T(0));
}
```

Say you call `sgn(42)`.  Because `42` is an `int`, `sgn<int>` will be need to be instantiated so the signature becomes `int sgn(int val)` to match the call.  Then the body becomes `return (int(0) < val) - (val < T(0));`, which makes two boolean tests:

- is 0 less than val?  (another way of saying, is val > 0?)
- is val less than 0?

Each of these tests yields a `true` or `false` boolean result, and in an arithmetic context (which is created by using a `-` on the boolean values), `true` implicitly converts to `1`, and `false` implicitly converts to `0`.

So, the possible values are:

```
             (0 < val) - (val < 0)
val > 0      (true - false) == 1 - 0 == 1
val == 0     (false - false) == 0 - 0 == 0
val < 0      (false - true) == 0 - 1 == -1
```

So the `sgn` function returns 1 if val is positive, 0 if it's 0, and -1 if it's negative.  Put another way, it returns an `int` indicative of the sign of `val`.

If you'd instantiated `sgn` for another type - say `double` - you'd get logically equivalent behaviour for doubles from a distinct instantiation of the template, with machine code instructions suitable for comparing `double`s.

> Where in the code do we actually declare what attributes T has and fit under that template?

We don't declare what attributes T has to have, but it is implicit in the use we make of T and the `val` variable of `T` type: firstly, there's the `T(0)` construction that must be supported, and secondly, we must be able to use `<` to compare `T` values and get a boolean result back (well, there's nothing checking it returns a bool, but that's normal for `operator<` and if it returned something else, the `-` logic would probably break).

> Is that what `mypair` is being declared as in the next block?

No - the `T` used for `sgn` is distinct from any other use of `T` in the program.

> Templates have the common attributes across classes that you want to be able to use.

It's hard to even know what you're thinking about there.  A template like `sgn` doesn't even involve a `class`.

---

Discussing the other code snippet:

```
template <class T>
class mypair {
    T a, b;
  public:
    mypair (T first, T second)
      {a=first; b=second;}
    T getmax ();
};

template <class T>
T mypair<T>::getmax ()
{
  T retval;
  retval = a>b? a : b;
  return retval;
}
```

Above, `getmax` is defined out-of-line, but all that is equivalent to:

```
template <class T>
class mypair {
    T a, b;
  public:
    mypair (T first, T second)
    {a=first; b=second;}

    T getmax() {
      T retval;
      retval = a>b? a : b;
      return retval;
    }
}
```

When you call the constructor, it will work out a unifying type based on the first and second arguments.  For example, if you called with `mypair{12, 45.2}` it will decide that `T = double` is suitable, and instantiate the class template for `double`.  You can then simply think of the behaviour the code would have by mentally replacing `T` everywhere with `double`.  You can also explicitly instantiate a template: `mypair<double>{4, 8}` would have `T`, and therefore `a` and `b`, be `double`s, so the return type of `getmax()` would also be a `double`.  (The `getmax()` function should be made `const`, as it doesn't need to mutate any data members).