# Is it possible to set an int/float without affecting it's sign?

Tags: c++, c

I have a list of numbers that may be positive/negative/zero, and I want to compare them to exactly -1, 0, 1 without if-then-else statements. Is that possible by setting non-zero numbers to 1, but leaving it's original sign either negative/positive?

EG. Setting -0.6 to -1, and setting 0.8 to 1, and leaving 0 as 0.

Comment: "_I want to compare them to exactly -1, 0, 1 without if-then-else statements_": Have you tested whether the compiler doesn't make this optimization by itself anyway?

Comment: You are going to need to perform a boolean test of *some* kind; what's the problem with `if-then-else` ?

Comment: In this list of numbers, do the number get larger than `-1` or `1`, i.e. will numbers like -6.5 or 5 show up in the list

Comment: `x = (x > 0) - (x < 0);`? It's the shortest way to spell it I know.

Comment: C or C++? They're different languages and the result would be very different. Choose only one language

Comment: You should look for signum function. C++ standard has something like copysign. Various methods exists (like what @HolyBlackCat mentioned)

Comment: [Is there a standard sign function (signum, sgn) in C/C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1903954/995714)