# n is negative, positive or zero? return 1, 2, or 4

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bit, bit-shift

I'm building a PowerPC interpreter, and it works quite well. In the Power architecture the condition register CR0 (EFLAGS on x86) is updated on almost any instruction. It is set like this. The value of CR0 is 1, if the last result was negative, 2 if the last result was positive, 4 otherwise.

My first naive method to interpret this is:

```
if (n < 0)
    cr0 = 1
else if (n > 0)
    cr0 = 2;
else
    cr0 = 4;
```

However I understand that all those branches won't be optimal, being run millions of times per second. I've seen some bit hacking on SO, but none seemed adeguate. For example I found many examples to convert a number to -1, 0, or 1 accordingly to the sign or 0. But how to make -1 = 1, 1 = 2, 0 = 4?
I'm asking for the help of the Bit Hackers...

Thanks in advance

**Update:**
First of all: thanks guys, you've been great. I'll test all of your codes carefully for speed and you'll be the first to know who's the winner.

@jalf: About your first advice, I wasn't actually calculating CR0 on every instruction. I was rather keeping a lastResult variable, and when (and if) a following instruction asked for a flag, do the comparison. Three main motivations took me back to "everytime" update:

1. On PPC you're not forced to update CR0 like on x86 (where ADD always change EFLAGS, even if not needed), you have two flavours of ADD, one updating. If the compiler chooses to use the updating one, it means that it's going to use the CR0 at some point, so there no point at delaying...
2. There's a particularly painful instruction called mtcrf, that enables you to change the CR0 arbitrarly. You can even set it to 7, with no arithmetic meaning... This just destroys the possibility of keeping a "lastResult" variable.

Comment: How do you know bit twiddling will be faster?

Comment: Just as a note to answerers, could we try to write answers that amount to more than just "don't ask this question"? Can we *either* assume that the OP is curious about implementing this himself, instead of relying on the compiler, or that, for whatever reason, the compiler's generated code has been tried and inspected, and found too slow? Or, failing that, give a better reason to ignore the issue than just "you should close your eyes, trust the compiler and hope for the best"

Comment: Which CPU is your interpreter running on? Knowing the instruction set might be necessary if you want anything near an optimal solution

Comment: +1.  Nice question, and lots of interesting answers.  Can you try all of them and post a little benchmark?

Comment: Note that even if he does, a benchmark won't necessarily tell *you* anything. Your compiler, your CPU, even your OS might lead to different results

Comment: related: [Branchless code that maps zero, negative, and positive to 0, 1, 2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1610836/995714)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

First, if this variable is to be updated after (nearly) every instruction, the obvious piece of advice is this:

*don't*

Only update it when the subsequent instructions need its value. At any other time, there's no point in updating it.

But anyway, when we update it, what we want is this behavior:

```
R < 0  => CR0 == 0b001 
R > 0  => CR0 == 0b010
R == 0 => CR0 == 0b100
```

Ideally, we won't need to branch at all. Here's one possible approach:

1. Set CR0 to the value `1`. (if you really want speed, investigate whether this can be done without fetching the constant from memory. Even if you have to spend a couple of instructions on it, it may well be worth it)
2. If R >= 0, left shift by one bit.
3. If R == 0, left shift by one bit

Where steps 2 and 3 can be transformed to eliminate the "if" part

```
CR0 <<= (R >= 0);
CR0 <<= (R == 0);
```

Is this faster? I don't know. As always, when you are concerned about performance, you need to measure, measure, measure.

However, I can see a couple of advantages of this approach:

1. we avoid branches completely
2. we avoid memory loads/stores.
3. the instructions we rely on (bit shifting and comparison) should have low latency, which isn't always the case for multiplication, for example.

The downside is that we have a dependency chain between all three lines: Each modifies CR0, which is then used in the next line. This limits instruction-level parallelism somewhat.

To minimize this dependency chain, we could do something like this instead:

```
CR0 <<= ((R >= 0) + (R == 0));
```

so we only have to modify CR0 once, after its initialization.

Or, doing everything in a single line:

```
CR0 = 1 << ((R >= 0) + (R == 0));
```

Of course, there are a lot of possible variations of this theme, so go ahead and experiment.

Comment: Actually `CR0` is a variable so you don't avoid memory loads and stores if `CR0` is in memory (this is an interpreter). It might be better to combine the assignments into one like `CR0 = 1 << (R >= 0) << (R == 0);` +1 though.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: a variable which can be kept in a register. Of course, it has to be loaded into that register *at some point*, but my code doesn't have to do it. If it was already in a register (and as a variable that is frequently modified, it very well might be), then we don't have to either load it or store it.

Comment: One assignment is usually better than two if you're going for optimisation. Also, why is a `+` more efficient than a `<<`?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your suggestion (and deleted my comment as a result). I would expect `+` and `<<` to have the same latency (without having looked it up), so I don't think one is more efficient than the other. Note that moving the `1` into that single line doesn't really change anything though. It's the same amount of work for the compiler (get a constant 1 from somewhere, and then shift it). But at this level, "assignments" don't really exist. Any reasonable compiler is able to represent variables by different registers at different times.

Comment: So assigning to X doesn't have to mean "overwrite the register where the old value of X was stored". It can just as well mean "store the value into a new register, and refer to that for further computations", which is exactly the same as would be done if you avoided the assignment

Comment: Thanks... this looks like a very good one. I'll write some tests to calculate times for it.

Comment: This works if you fix the grouping, needs to be `1 << ((R >= 0) + (R == 0))`

Comment: And it seems to be the fastest.

Answer (score 20):

Lots of answers that are approximately "don't" already, as usual :) You want the bit hack? You will get it. Then feel free to use it or not as *you* see fit.

You could use that mapping to -1, 0 and 1 (`sign`), and then do this:

```
return 7 & (0x241 >> ((sign(x) + 1) * 4));
```

Which is essentially using a tiny lookup table.

Or the "naive bithack":

```
int y = ((x >> 31) & 1) | ((-x >> 31) & 2)
return (~(-y >> 31) & 4) | y;
```

The first line maps `x < 0` to 1, `x > 0` to 2 and `x == 0` to 0. The second line then maps `y == 0` to 4 and `y != 0` to y.

---

And of course it has a sneaky edge case for x = 0x80000000 which is mapped to 3. Oops. Well let's fix that:

```
int y = ((x >> 31) & 1) | ((-x >> 31) & 2)
y &= 1 | ~(y << 1);  // remove the 2 if odd
return (~(-y >> 31) & 4) | y;
```

Comment: Best write some unit tests.  After that, check your implementation of `sign(x)` to make sure it doesn't have any branches.  Use a profiler to make sure this actually is faster.

Comment: @BenVoigt: well yes, I believe it goes without saying that you should test your code.

Comment: @jalf: Well, when I posted that comment, the expression was `7 & (0x241 >> sign(x))` which gives wrong results, I think in every single case.

Comment: @BenVoigt yes, I accidentally "tab-entered", even though the post wasn't even nearly finished. The only *actual* mistake I made was forgetting about the int.MinValue edge-case.

Comment: The final version works once the missing semicolon is added, but it is very very slow.

Comment: @BenVoigt I would expect so yes, if I counted correctly it has a dependency chain of length 13, and the first one shouldn't be fast either.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't expect this to be the fastest, but not "very slow" either. Just goes to show how dangerous assumptions are when optimizing. :)

Comment: @harold: If you accidentally submit an answer early, you can immediately delete it, edit while it is deleted, and undelete when finished.  Otherwise people will waste their time considering and commenting your post.

Comment: For some reason, my MinGW G++ _really does not like_ this code.  VC++10 says this takes about twice as long as the others, G++ says 5 times longer than the others. Most tests are 1-4s, this code is just shy of 15s.

Answer (score 6):

The following expression is a little cryptic, but not excessively so, and it looks to be something the compiler can optimize pretty easily:

```
cr0 = 4 >> ((2 * (n < 0)) + (n > 0));
```

Here's what GCC 4.6.1 for an x86 target compiles it to with `-O2`:

```
xor ecx, ecx
mov eax, edx
sar eax, 31
and eax, 2
test    edx, edx
setg    cl
add ecx, eax
mov eax, 4
sar eax, cl
```

And VC 2010 with `/Ox` looks pretty similar:

```
xor ecx, ecx
test eax, eax
sets cl
xor edx, edx
test eax, eax
setg dl
mov eax, 4
lea ecx, DWORD PTR [edx+ecx*2]
sar eax, cl
```

The version using `if` tests compiles to assembly that uses jumps with either of these compilers.  Of course, you'll never really be sure what any particular compiler is going to do with whatever particular bit of code you choose unless you actually examine the output.  My expression is cryptic enough that unless it was really a performance critical bit of code, I might still go with with `if` statement version.  Since you need to set the CR0 register frequently, I think it might be worth measuring if this expression helps at all.

Answer (score 4):

gcc with no optimization

```
        movl    %eax, 24(%esp)  ; eax has result of reading n
        cmpl    $0, 24(%esp)
        jns     .L2
        movl    $1, 28(%esp)
        jmp     .L3
.L2:
        cmpl    $0, 24(%esp)
        jle     .L4
        movl    $2, 28(%esp)
        jmp     .L3
.L4:
        movl    $4, 28(%esp)
.L3:
```

With -O2:

```
        movl    $1, %edx       ; edx = 1
        cmpl    $0, %eax
        jl      .L2            ; n < 0
        cmpl    $1, %eax       ; n < 1
        sbbl    %edx, %edx     ; edx = 0 or -1
        andl    $2, %edx       ; now 0 or 2
        addl    $2, %edx       ; now 2 or 4
.L2:
        movl    %edx, 4(%esp)
```

I don't think you are likely to do much better

Comment: First, actually posting the disassembly is really nice. It's definitely the only sane starting point when trying to optimize on this level. But secondly, there's a branch in GCCs code, and I suspect you could speed things up by eliminating that. It's not just about the number of instructions, after all, but also how the CPU executes them. :)

Comment: The limit on speed is number of memory operations.  Other than reading the instructions, the only memory op in the optimized version is one store to the stack.

Comment: Not *just* the number of memory operations. There are a lot of factors at play. You're right that memory ops tend to dominate, but in their absence, other factors can be significant. My gut feeling is that the branch-less implementations would be faster (and in about the same number of instructions too, if not fewer),but obviously, that needs to be tested. GCC's code might be faster for all I know

Comment: @jalf I tried compiling your code.  Even on -O3 gcc does not do a very good job of reducing the number of operations, so it ends up as 17 instructions with no branches and just the one store.

Comment: Curious. Others are reporting that my answer clocks in at 9 instructions (I haven't tried compiling and disassembling it myself)

Answer (score 4):

I was working on this one when my computer crashed.

```
int cr0 = (-(n | n-1) >> 31) & 6;
cr0 |= (n >> 31) & 5;
cr0 ^= 4;
```

Here's the resulting assembly (for Intel x86):

```
PUBLIC  ?tricky@@YAHH@Z                                 ; tricky
; Function compile flags: /Ogtpy
_TEXT   SEGMENT
_n$ = 8                                                 ; size = 4
?tricky@@YAHH@Z PROC                                    ; tricky
; Line 18
        mov     ecx, DWORD PTR _n$[esp-4]
        lea     eax, DWORD PTR [ecx-1]
        or      eax, ecx
        neg     eax
        sar     eax, 31                                 ; 0000001fH
; Line 19
        sar     ecx, 31                                 ; 0000001fH
        and     eax, 6
        and     ecx, 5
        or      eax, ecx
; Line 20
        xor     eax, 4
; Line 22
        ret     0
?tricky@@YAHH@Z ENDP                                    ; tricky
```

And a complete exhaustive test which is also reasonably suitable for benchmarking:

```
#include <limits.h>

int direct(int n)
{
    int cr0;
    if (n < 0)
        cr0 = 1;
    else if (n > 0)
        cr0 = 2;
    else
        cr0 = 4;
    return cr0;
}

const int shift_count = sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT - 1;
int tricky(int n)
{
    int cr0 = (-(n | n-1) >> shift_count) & 6;
    cr0 |= (n >> shift_count) & 5;
    cr0 ^= 4;
    return cr0;
}

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
int main(void)
{
    int i = 0;
    do {
        if (direct(i) != tricky(i)) {
            std::cerr << std::hex << i << std::endl;
            return i;
        }
    } while (++i);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 And since you seem to benchmark all the proposed solutions, maybe you could post some results (at least for the working ones)? When benchmarking, what about some random shuffling of the input bits to distract the branch predictor and make it a more "real-life" test?

Comment: Shouldn't the test be more random if it is to be used to benchmarking? This way the branchy version would look much better than it really is.

Comment: @harold: It's definitely not an ideal benchmark, but it gives a better indication of speed than merely counting assembly instructions.

Comment: that's true. :) creating accurate benchmarks is extremely hard though. A simple benchmark is fine as long as you're aware of its limitations.

Comment: Ideally you'd also like to know something about the actual distribution of inputs.  Probably 50% positive, 25% zero, 25% negative would be better than uniform.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a faster method, the compiler probably already is using it.

Keep your code short and simple; that makes the optimizer most effective.

The simple straightforward solution does surprisingly well speed-wise:

```
cr0 = n? (n < 0)? 1: 2: 4;
```

x86 Assembly (produced by VC++ 2010, flags `/Ox`):

```
PUBLIC  ?tricky@@YAHH@Z                                 ; tricky
; Function compile flags: /Ogtpy
_TEXT   SEGMENT
_n$ = 8                                                 ; size = 4
?tricky@@YAHH@Z PROC                                    ; tricky
; Line 26
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR _n$[esp-4]
        test    eax, eax
        je      SHORT $LN3@tricky
        xor     ecx, ecx
        test    eax, eax
        setns   cl
        lea     eax, DWORD PTR [ecx+1]
; Line 31
        ret     0
$LN3@tricky:
; Line 26
        mov     eax, 4
; Line 31
        ret     0
?tricky@@YAHH@Z ENDP                                    ; tricky
```

Comment: I wouldn't be so sure in this case. PowerPC doesn't seem to have integer conditional move instructions.

Comment: And if the compiler isn't already using the fastest method? I agree with the second line, but what about the cases where you need more than what the compiler can generate for you?

Comment: An emulator is one of the few counter-examples to the "short and simple" pattern, where a small performance benefit (if it exists) can pay off very quickly.

Comment: @Mysticial: It matters whether the host platform has those instructions, the emulated platform has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Right... I misread part of the question. I thought it was running natively on PowerPC.

Comment: Yes, and the compiler magically transforms those three ifs into a simple 3-instruction-bit-hack if it is faster. You got a really nice compiler, want to share it? Even if it did, that's just a comment diguised as an answer.

Comment: @Christian: Please show your three instruction bit hack.  The shortest one I've seen here is nine (jalf's final expression, with added parentheses).

Comment: @BenVoigt Well Ok, maybe I exaggerated, but I would still be surprised if the compiler would produce this solution (or any one that's fastest). I could believe it, but I have to see it to do so. Blind trust into the compiler doesn't help always (and has already disappointed me sometimes). Not that I eagerly employ "premature optimization" (and your advice is good in general), but the OP certainly asked for it.

Comment: @ChristianRau: Have to compare assembly to find out what's actually being generated in this case, but I've learned about some very nifty tricks (like multiplying and shifting in order to perform integral division by a constant) only to find that my compiler was already using it automatically.

Comment: @BenVoigt Wow +2 for actually proving the compiler's superiority in this case. In fact it seems to use exactly jalf's solution. I know the compiler does small things like shifting for multiplication, but I hadn't thought it to be that intelligent. Which one was it (from the not so ugly assembly syntax I guess it wasn't GCC)?

Comment: @ChristianRau: Oh no, I may have copied assembler from an old run of the compiler... going to verify now.  As you surmised, that was in fact jalf's version.  The optimizer's code is slightly worse.

Answer (score 1):

For a completely unportable approach, I wonder if this might have any speed benefit:

```
void func(signed n, signed& cr0) {
    cr0 = 1 << (!(unsigned(n)>>31)+(n==0));
}

mov         ecx,eax  ;with MSVC10, all optimizations except inlining on.
shr         ecx,1Fh  
not         ecx  
and         ecx,1  
xor         edx,edx  
test        eax,eax  
sete        dl  
mov         eax,1  
add         ecx,edx  
shl         eax,cl  
mov         ecx,dword ptr [cr0]  
mov         dword ptr [ecx],eax
```

compared to your code on my machine:

```
test        eax,eax            ; if (n < 0)
jns         func+0Bh (401B1Bh)  
mov         dword ptr [ecx],1  ; cr0 = 1;
ret                            ; cr0 = 2; else cr0 = 4; }
xor         edx,edx            ; else if (n > 0)
test        eax,eax  
setle       dl  
lea         edx,[edx+edx+2]  
mov         dword ptr [ecx],edx ; cr0 = 2; else cr0 = 4; }
ret
```

I don't know much at all about assembly, so I can't say for sure if this would have any benefit (or even if mine has any jumps.  I see no instructions beginning with j anyway).  As always, (and as everyone else said a million times) PROFILE.

I doubt this is faster than say Jalf or Ben's, but I didn't see any that took advantage of the fact that on x86 all negative numbers have a certain bit set, and I figured I'd throw one out.

[EDIT]BenVoigt suggests `cr0 = 4 >> ((n != 0) + (unsigned(n) >> 31));` to remove the logical negation, and my tests show that is a *vast* improvement.

Comment: I think that `2 << ((n == 0) - (unsigned(n) >> 31))` would be a tiny bit better, since it removes the need for logical negation.  Or perhaps `(2 << (n == 0)) - (unsigned(n) >> 31)`.

Comment: Or even `+ (n >> 31)`, using an arithmetic shift instead of logical shift.  Really don't think there's going to be any performance advantage with that one, though.

Comment: @BenVoigt: The code in that first comment of yours outperforms most on this page for most of my tests, but for my most recent round of tests, comes up with incorrect results.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Maybe the correct code should have been `cr0 = 4 >> ((n != 0) + (unsigned(n) >> 31));`  It's close to what you suggested, and outperforms all others.

Comment: Umm, yeah, I guess passing a negative shift count is undefined behavior, and your latest version fixes that.  So I suggest putting that in your answer.  Although my second variant (with the subtraction outside the shift) shouldn't have suffered from UB.

Answer (score -1):

The following is my attempt.

```
int cro = 4 >> (((n > 0) - (n < 0)) % 3 + (n < 0)*3);
```