# Get 1, 0, -1 as positive, zero, or negative for an integer with math only

Tags: algorithm

I have a situation where I'm performing a calculate over a huge number of rows, and I can really increase the performance if I can eschew a conditional statement.

What I need is for a given positive, zero, or negative integer I want the result 1, 0, -1 respectively.

So if I do `col/ABS(col)`, I will get 1 for a positive number, and -1 for a negative number, but of course if `col` equals 0 then I'll get an error.  I can't get an error.

This seems simple enough, but I can't wrap my ahead around it.

Comment: Hmmm, what's the impact of multiplying the term you already have by `col` ?

Comment: Depending on the language, you can say: `if not value return 0; else return value/abs(value)`.

Comment: `col/max(1, abs(col))`? Ugly but works. (For integers, that is.)

Comment: I think the point was to avoid another conditional - both those statements will mean another conditional.

Comment: other than stripping out zeros how do you expect to know if your value is zero?  DivByZero errors are going to happen

Comment: Some inspiration here, perhaps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610836/branchless-code-that-maps-zero-negative-and-positive-to-0-1-2

Comment: What operations are available?  Some languages allow boolean results of comparisons to be treated as integers (and so you can do arithmetic on terms like `(x < 0)`).

Comment: Are you really sure the conditional is the bottbottleneck? Can you provide some profiling information backing that up?

Comment: I was doing this in SSAS tabular, and the query plan is exceeds 10,000 lines.  I couldn't use the accepted answer exactly but I did something similar and it reduced the time it took by 40%.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a standard sign function (signum, sgn) in C/C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903954/is-there-a-standard-sign-function-signum-sgn-in-c-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`col/max(1, abs(col))`

Ugly but works. For integers, that is. For floating point values where there's no well-defined smallest positive value, you're stuck unless the language allows you to look into it as a bit sequence, then you can just do the same with the sign flag and the significand.

Whether this helps optimising anything is highly debatable though. It certainly makes things harder to read.

Comment: Thanks, this works.  I'll check you as soon as I can.  In my application IF statements get offloaded to a different engine.  I don't know if Max will help or not, but this is what I was looking for.

Comment: but max is just a wrapper of an if statement...  this isn't making much sense to me

Comment: @TMcKeown Yeah, that's why it's a bit suspicious to me. But as OP says, if there are two different engines at work, a fast one that has `max()` hard-coded into it and a slow one that processes `if` statements (something like SQL and PLSQL), and it avoids context-switching, it may just work.

Comment: Both `abs` and `max` *could* be coded in a branchless fashion, but then you really need to define such, and I can't think of a branchless `abs` that doesn't use a branchless two-way `sign`, so you're nearly half-way there once you go down that route.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming either two's complement 32-bit integers, or one's complement with no negative-zero to worry about, then the following works well:

```
(x>>31) - (-x>>31);
```

Replace `31` with `63` for 64-bit integers, and so on.

Comment: That's smart since the sign will be on the last bit.  I can't use this, but it's a good answer.

Comment: Isn't this backwards? For a positive integer you'd get `0 - 1`?

Comment: @beaker no, you'd get `0 - -1`, which is `1`.

Comment: Ah, arithmetic shift vs. logical shift. Yes, I see now that for arithmetic shift yours is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing this in an SSAS tabular model, which doesn't have a MAX function like in @bizclop's answer (which helps in many other applications such as EXCEL).

I ended up doing the following which was inspired by the accepted answer:

```
ROUND([col] / (ABS([col]) + 1), 0)
```

This ended up reducing my query time quite significantly (40%) versus `IF([col] <> 0, [col]/ABS([col], 0)`.